# asp.net MVC 3 Razor/Linq

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm getting this error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type ``` System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery``1[<>f__AnonymousType1``2[System.DateTime,System.Int32]] ```, but this dictionary requires a model item of type ``` System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable``1[AtAClick.Models.WhatsOn] ```.

This is my controller;

```
public ViewResult Index(WhatsOn model)
{       
   DateTime myDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);

   var datequery =
            db.WhatsOns.Where(c => c.start > myDate).OrderByDescending(c => c.start).GroupBy(c => c.start).Select(
                sGroup => new
                              {
                                  day = sGroup.Key,
                                  whtscount = sGroup.Count()
                              });

   return View(datequery);
}
```

I want to return all entries after todays date and the number of entries. I'm new to this, any help is greatly apprecieted! Thanks in advance, if you need any mjore detail just let me know. Thanks!

This is my view

==============================

```
@model IEnumerable<AtAClick.Models.WhatsOn>

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Index"; }

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>start</th>
        <th>end</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Desc</th>
        <th>link</th>
        <th>CalenderDisplay</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.day)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.whtscount)</td>          
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

============================

This is the edit method in my controller;

//
        // GET: /WhatsOn/Edit/5

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        WhatsOn whatson = db.WhatsOns.Find(id);
        return View(whatson);
    }

    //
    // POST: /WhatsOn/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(WhatsOn whatson)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(whatson).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(whatson);
    }
```

Comment: can you edit your post and include the code for your view?

Comment: Yep, I'll pop it in now... Done. The editor hasd taken out the table tags. It's actually magled it a bit, but the foreach is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is a mismatch between what your view expects and what your controller is passing.

In your select statement your selecting a new anonymous type but your view is expecting the type `IEnumerable<WhatsOn>`

assuming the whats on fields are day and whtscount then replace the datequery with

```
    var datequery =
        db.WhatsOns.Where(c => c.start > myDate).OrderByDescending(c => c.start).GroupBy(c => c.start).Select(
            sGroup => new WhatsOn()
                          {
                              day = sGroup.Key,
                              whtscount = sGroup.Count()
                          });
```

**Update:**
The error is indicating that your select query cannot be translated into the equivilent sql, what you could try is changing it to

```
    var datequery =
        db.WhatsOns.Where(c => c.start > myDate).OrderByDescending(c => c.start).GroupBy(c => c.start).AsEnumerable().Select(
            sGroup => new WhatsOn
                          {
                              day = sGroup.Key,
                              whtscount = sGroup.Count()
                          });
```

**Update:** I think the issue may be that when you get to the post method of the edit, the WhatsOn object is no longer associated with the database WhatsOn it was originally loaded from, have a go at changing it to

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    WhatsOn whatson = db.WhatsOns.Find(id);
    return View(whatson);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    WhatsOn whatsOnmodel = db.WhatsOns.Find(id);

    if (TryUpdateModel(whatsOnmodel))
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(whatsOnmodel );
}
```

**Update:** If that approach was not working you could see if your one did just add the loading at the beginning so

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, WhatsOn whatson)
{
    WhatsOn whatsOnmodel = db.WhatsOns.Find(id);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        whatsOnmodel.day = whatson.day;
        whatsOnmodel.whtscount = whatson.whtscount;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(whatsOnmodel);
}
```

you could test that and see what happens

**Update:**
Actually i think your first approach should of worked but i think it requires the Id, what happens if you make it

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, WhatsOn whatson)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(whatson).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(whatson);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, thst's gotten me a little further, but now I'm getting this error... The entity or complex type 'AtAClick.Models.WhatsOn' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.  Do I have to edit the foreach in the view to handle this query? Thanks again!

Comment: This worked without having to use DTO. It's grouping them by date and returniong the count! But, when I try and edit an entry I get this error, feel free to stop helping me by the way, I know it's error after error.. anyway, Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries... Any advice? I'll be marking your answer as correct either way!

Comment: @Dan would you mind posting the post method of your controller where you are trying to update the records

Comment: It's  posted now. Thanks for all this Manatherin!

Comment: on 'whatsOnmodel.day = whatson.day;'   I get 'Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'...

Comment: if I change it to that I get the 'Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.' error.

Comment: @Dan that sounds like your view is returning a null whatson object, was the model passed into the view null?

Comment: @Dan take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836173/entity-framework-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpect this is the same error you are getting it may be the same issue

Comment: Thanks Matherin, you have been a great help! The model passed into the view is  not null, there are a number of entries. I have read that question. I'll keep going with it and see how I get on. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your view is expecting an `IEnumerable<AtAClick.Models.WhatsOn>`, but you are passing a collection of anonymous types. You should change your projection (`Select`) to instantiate instances of your `WhatsOn` type instead.

**Update**

You will need to create a new data transfer object (DTO) type to project onto (e.g. WhatsOnDto), as WhatsOn is an entity type. See [The entity cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325797/the-entity-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query) for more info. Update your view's model type to an `IEnumerable<WhatsOnDto>`, or better still a `MyViewModel` type which contains a property of `WhatsOnDtos`.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what Manatheirn also suggested. I implemented his soloution but got the error I just posted in a comment below his answer. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'll try this now and report back, thanks again, I really appreciate this! 2 mins!

Comment: I added the class WhatDTO to my WhatsOn.cs model and made the changed you suggested. This worked! But now when I try and edit/update/insert an entry I get the previous error.

Comment: This is difficult without the code, which error are you getting?

Comment: Hi dev, Matherin's updated answer below worked, it's grouping them by date and returning the count. Though when I try and update an entry I get this error (as I said, feel free to get back to whatever you were doing, you've helped me a lot so far!) ....  Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.... any advice?