# Solution for: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, triggers

I found a solution for people who get an exception:

*Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.*

But, anyway I have question.

I read topic:
[Entity Framework: "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836173/entity-framework-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpect)
*To **VMAtm, Robert Harvey***

In my case I had for example table articles:

```
Articles
------------
article_id
title
date_cr
date_mod
deleted
```

And I had trigger:

```
create trigger articles_instead_of_insert 
on articles instead of insert 
as      
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    insert into articles(
        article_id, 
        title, 
        date_cr,
        date_mod, 
        deleted
    )
    select 
        user_id, 
        title, 
        isnull(date_cr, {fn NOW()}),
        isnull(date_mod, {fn NOW()}),
        isnull(deleted, 0)
    from inserted;
go
```

When I delete this trigger then I dont get this exception. So this trigger is problem. And now I have a question - Why? Should I do something?

Comment: Are you using stored procedures? Is NoCount on?

Comment: Great VMAtm Robert, Maby you should read all my post before close? I read this post that you give a link to.

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate. The other one has answers about optimistic concurrency. The problem here is that the trigger should include a `SET NOCOUNT ON` statement or EF will be confused.

Comment: I change my trigger but I had still the same exception. I put SET NOCOUNT ON after as statement. Look my edit.

Comment: Why do you have a trigger at all? Looking at it, it appears all you really need are default values for date_cr, date_mod,and deleted. Defaults tend to perform better than triggers and should be used if they can be. I'd probably also use IsDeleted for the columnname instead as deleted is the name of a trigger pseudotable and it's confusing especially in a trigger.

Comment: You're right in this case. But this trigger I wrote here is only example. My real trigger is different. That should only highlight the problem. But not trigger was the problem; that was only conjuncture.

Comment: Seeing the question and later comments: voting to close as not reproducible. The question doesn't reflect the real problem.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Solution:

```
try {
    context.SaveChanges();
} catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException) {
    context.Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins, db.Articles);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Refresh method resolves concurency conflicts be refreshing the object context. The first parameter tell which values should win. Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb896255(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I was having this issue too, but couldn't find `Refresh`. This helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177718/dbcontext-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-refresh

Comment: hmm... I think solution would be to use lock mechanism rather just overwriting values

Comment: Some additional explanation in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11772953/12484

Answer (score 6):

Its better you update your save method like this..... In case you calling `savechange()` method of entity context after every addobject and deleteobject or modification :

```
public void Save(object entity)
{
    using (var transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            SaveChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
         }
         catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException)
         {
             if (ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity).State == EntityState.Deleted || ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity).State == EntityState.Modified)
                    this.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, entity);
              else if (ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity).State == EntityState.Added)
                    Detach(entity);
              AcceptAllChanges(); 
              transaction.Commit();
          }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have `SET NOCOUNT ON`.
The EF SQL Statement that it generates ALWAYS adds a clause of `where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [ID] = scope_identity()` (for example).
Notice the `where @@ROWCOUNT > 0` clause.  Take off your `SET NOCOUNT ON` statement and it should work.

Comment: Did you read comments? There was written that I used set nocount on and before it I didnt used it.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem, however, removing the SET NOCOUNT ON didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, need to set DatabaseGenerated Attribute when Custom Code First Conventions

```
public class Car
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public DateTime Registered { get; set; }
}
```

or

> Switching off Identity for Numeric Primary Keys
>   The following example sets the DepartmentID property to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None to indicate that the value will not be generated by the database.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().Property(t => t.DepartmentID)
.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

see https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/custom

and https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/databasegenerated-attribute

and https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties

Answer (score 1):

Possible Problem:
You placed a ReadOnlyAttribute in you entity key's metadata, which causes its value to become zero

```
 [DisplayName("Student ID")]
 [ReadOnly(true)]
 public int StudentID { get; set; }
```

Solution:
Remove the ReadOnlyAttribute

```
 [DisplayName("Student ID")]
 public int StudentID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this error message is a rather mystifying one. The answer from webtrifusion helped me. See [Entity Framework: "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836173/entity-framework-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpec)

It turns out I forgot to add "Id:0" in the JSON on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

I had InsertAsync setting EntityState to Modified implementing a [Repository pattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnPPItvvNB0). When Debugging I spotted the [entity's id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx) was 0

```
    public async Task InsertAsync(T entity)
    {

        dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Changing the Entity State to Added fixed it.

```
    dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same error then I realized that I forgot the set primary key in table and setting increment values...

Answer (score 0):

I found this error when i updating entity 
and forgot to pass Primary key value....

So Entity can update record with reference with Primary key

Solution : Check whether primary key value is pass or not to update the given record. :)

Comment: This isn't a complete answer to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

When using `RowVersion` as **Tracking Property**, to control concurrency in multi-user system, `RowVersion` which is auto generated by database engine by default, should be passed as **Hidden Field** in the view when Editing/Updating a record, the same way we manage the `Key Identity` Field:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RowVersion) 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Entity Framework Code first,

using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext ( )) {..

Adding this after the using line:

```
db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
```

Comment: The default value is true already, From MSDN: "Gets or sets a value indicating whether tracked entities should be validated automatically when SaveChanges is invoked. The default value is true."