# Exception when try to modify my model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

when I try to add in my model some note appear [Exception](http://img440.imageshack.us/img440/7843/gks.png)

Here is my CompetitionRepository where I implement method

```
 public void AddCompetition(Competition competition)
   {
       if (competition.ID == 0)
            _context.Competitions.Add(competition);
       else
            _context.Entry(competition).State = EntityState.Modified;

       _context.SaveChanges();

   }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]   
    public ActionResult AdminPCreate(string compName, int quantity, DateTime starTime)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
            _dataManager.Competitions.AddCompetition(
                new Competition
                {
                    ID = 1,
                    Quantity = quantity,
                    StartTime = starTime,
                });
        return View("Competitions",GetCompetitions());
    }
```

And cshtml Page, maybe I'm doing something wrong

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AdminPCreate", "Home"))
{

    @Html.TextBox("compName",null ,new {@placeholder = "Competition Name"})
    @Html.TextBox("quantity", null, new {@placeholder = "Amount players"})
    @Html.TextBox("starTime", null, new {@placeholder = "Enter beginnig of the match like dd\\mm\\yyyy"})

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success"/>
```

I also tried using a lot of solutions including here on that site, such as [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819813/solution-for-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpected-n)
because when i try to use that  (ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity)`
because my field methods have type different from object

```
public void AddCompetition(Competition competition)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the method `AdminPCreate` of your controller, you have `new Competition { ID = 1, [..] }`.

That `ID` valueof `1` makes your repository think it's an existing item, so Entity Framework tries to update the `Competition` record where `ID = 1`. That doesn't exist, so your database returns "0 rows affected" and the error is thrown.

I suspect that when you set the `ID` to `0` instead of `1` in your controller it'll work.

Comment: ok, when i set id to 0 it show me such exception 'Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id'

Comment: @user make sure it is an identity (auto-increment) column.

Comment: in DB ID is(auto-increment).. and i must make it in my model too?

Comment: yes.. the problem was in autoincrement attribue..  i done some foreign keys in table, which blocked main entity ID.. thx, now everything work..