# Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

In Using EF6 in C# :- 
i have Model A which has Model B and C inside it.

```
class A
{
    Guid Id;
    B b;
    C c;

    public A()
    {
        Id = new Guid;
    }
}

class B
{
    Guid Id;

    public B()
    {
        Id = new Guid;
    }
}
```

When model A saved in database (without B and C) its working fine. When i fetch it from database and then create new B and assign it to A and try to save it. Getting error

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.
>
> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.

(I have all the keys as GUID). 
On further debug i can see EntityKey is null for B in Exception.
[image]

I have tired this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819813/solution-for-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpected-n),[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836173/entity-framework-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpec?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) but non of this solution are working.

Comment: Fetch `A` with `B` `Include()`-ed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would use properties instead of fields.

Then as I see you have a one-to-one relationship between `A` and `B` and also between `A` and `C` where `B` and `C` are optional.

> **"When configuring one-to-one relationships,
>   Entity Framework requires that the primary key of the dependent also be the
>   foreign key."** - *Programming Entity Framework Code First by Julia Lerman & Rowan Miller*

So the other problem is that in class `B` you set the value of `Id` through the constructor.

I would try this below:

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace EFExposeForeignKey
{
    public class A
    {
        public A()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        /* Other properties of A goes here */

        // Navigation property
        public B B { get; set; }

        // Navigation property
        public C C { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(EFExposeForeignKey.A.B))]
        // Or simply [ForeignKey("B")]
        // I wanted to emphasize here that "B" is NOT the type name but the name of a property in class "A"
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        /* Other properties of B goes here */

        // Navigation property
        public A A { get; set; }
    }

    public class C
    {
        [Key]
        [ForeignKey(nameof(EFExposeForeignKey.A.C))]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        /* Other properties of C goes here */

        // Navigation property
        public A A { get; set; }
    }
}
```