# Mapping DTO back to model with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper, dto

I have a Fixture model :

```
public partial class Fixture
{
    public int FixtureId { get; set; }
    public string Season { get; set; }
    public byte Week { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }

    //foreign key
    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

    public byte? AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
    public byte? HomeTeamScore { get; set; }
}
```

And a Fixture DTO :

```
public class FixtureDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Season { get; set; }
    public byte Week { get; set; }
    public string AwayTeamName { get; set; }
    public string HomeTeamName { get; set; }
    public byte? AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
    public byte? HomeTeamScore { get; set; }
}
```

I am using AutoMapper for the mapping and this is my first attempt using it.  Here is my mapping :

```
CreateMap<Fixture, FixtureDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FixtureId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AwayTeamName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AwayTeam.TeamName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.HomeTeamName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.HomeTeam.TeamName));
        CreateMap<FixtureDTO, Fixture>();
```

It works fine in taking the Fixture and mapping it to the FixtureDTO which I use to display the data.  But when I want to update the data and pass the FixtureDTO back to map it back to Fixture I get an error.

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutFixture(int id, FixtureDTO fixture)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && id == fixture.Id)
        {
            //do mapping manually here?

            var updated = _repository.UpdateFixture(Mapper.Map<Fixture>(fixture));
            return Request.CreateResponse(updated ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
```

This is the error I get :

```
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
```

Can anybody help with this?

EDIT : Reverse mapping :

```
CreateMap<Fixture, FixtureDTO>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FixtureId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AwayTeamName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AwayTeam.TeamName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.HomeTeamName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.HomeTeam.TeamName));
        CreateMap<FixtureDTO, Fixture>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FixtureId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.AwayTeam.TeamName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AwayTeamName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.HomeTeam.TeamName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.HomeTeamName));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension to @lazyberezovsky's answer:

This is an (untested) example of the reverse mapping you might require:

```
CreateMap<FixtureDTO, Fixture>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.FixtureId,
                   opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.AwayTeam,
                   opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new Team
                                                 {
                                                     TeamName = src.AwayTeamName
                                                 }))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.HomeTeam,
                   opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new Team
                                                 {
                                                     TeamName = src.HomeTeamName
                                                 }));
```

I've used this format in the past and its worked fine, but alternatively you could also create specific mappings for team. Eg:

```
CreateMap<string, Team>()....
```

Also, I presume you are doing it, but assert that your configuration is valid. Eg:

```
[Test]
public void AutoMapper_Configuration_IsValid()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(m => m.AddProfile<MyProfile>());
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

Comment: I think this is on the right track, but I have a problem with the fact that I have more than 1 team object, and the mapping does not map the TeamId so I end up with 2 teamIds of 0, which results in this error : 'An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key'.  Do I need to go into the database and also map the TeamIds?

Comment: There wasn't enough information in the question to define how `Team` should be mapped, so I simply adapted your mapping. You have a couple of options, either get the `Team.ID` in the original request and persist it via a hidden field in the view, or query the database using the team name to retrieve the ID again during postback.

Answer (score 0):

Generally that exception is thrown by EF when it detects one of the following:

*Opimistic Concurrency Violation*: This usually occurs when the entity you are trying to edit was modified else where during the time you loaded, edited and saved it. (see: [Entity Framework: "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836173/entity-framework-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpec))

*An Incorrectly set ID*: No ID set for Pks or FKs. I've also seen an exception like this when I mistakenly set an Entity's FK to a value and set the associated object to an object with a different ID.

Most likely this exception is being thrown because of some code in your repository. If you post the code in your repository we might get a better idea of what is causing the exception.

Comment: This is the relevant code in my repository : public bool UpdateFixture(Fixture fixture)
        {
            _db.Entry(fixture).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return true;
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

Comment: In that case I would assume that it is probably an issue with your mapping. @lazyberezovsky is right, by default you can't map TO child properties (e.g. `dest.AwayTeam.TeamName`), you would need to write your own custom resolver (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-value-resolvers).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create reverse mapping from DTO to entity (provide custom member mappings, if needed):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<FixtureDTO, Fixture>();
```

And second - retrieve, map, and update existing entity

```
if (ModelState.IsValid && id == fixture.Id)
{
    Fixture entity = _repository.FindById(fixture.Id);
    Mapper.Map(fixture, entity); // Use this mapping method!
    var updated = _repository.UpdateFixture(entity);
    // etc
}
```

Comment: The Mapper.Map line gives me the following error : "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\n\nMapping types:\r\nFixtureDTO -> Fixture_E5E73096DAC63B49875D0DFBD914D9991F1B1DE2AF3D92F26A5A11D99374E380\"}.  Why would it be trying to map FixtureDTO to Fixture_E5E73096DAC63B49875D0DFBD914D9991F1B1DE2AF3D92F26A5A11D99374E380?

Comment: @user517406 that's what I talked about in `First` part - you need to create map for this mapping. And automapper trying to map FixtureDTO to Fixture, because you need to update your Fixture.

Comment: Doing the reverse mapping from FixtureDTO to Fixture (see edit in original post) results in the error : Expression 'dest => dest.AwayTeam.TeamName' must resolve to top-level member and not any child object's properties. Use a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option instead.

Comment: @user517406 That's because of `AwayTeam` property (same with HomeTeam - because it is object of type Team). If you don't change team names in UI, then just ignore those properties on reverse mapping (remove mapping for those properties).