# why i can't save the current DateTime.Now using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
     using (var db = new MyEntities())
     {    
          var newGroup = new Groups
          {
              GroupDate = DateTime.Now,
              GroupName = "someName"
          };
          db.Groups.Add(newGroup);
          db.SaveChanges();
     }
     transaction.Complete();
 }
```

GroupId and GroupDate is PK, GroupId is Identity(step = 1) and GroupDate is not

can any one tell me why this exception happened when using a simple code like this and how to switch off the **Optimistic Concurrency Updates** if it's possible

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is in your case, but I don't recall `DateTime.Now` requiring anything special to work with an EF entity.

Comment: just try it it will throw that exception

Comment: What is the PK in your table?

Comment: Never worked with `TransactionScope`, but is it possible that you need to "switch" the two usings so the scope is inside the context, because after the end of the context using it is disposed and the transaction can not access the DB anymore? Because I use `DateTime.Now` a lot in combination with EF and did never have that problem...

Comment: [chrfin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/472434/chrfin) the same exception

Comment: Does it happen without the transaction? Can you show us the Code of `Groups`?

Comment: yes it does, groups is a entity in edmx model, each column has None in his concurrency Mode property

Comment: Do you have a valid key defined for the table?

Comment: Does the `Groups` class have references to other entities?

Comment: as i said in the question groups is just a table has tow PK groupId and groupDate and groupId is identity step 1

Comment: Then I have no idea, sorry. Maybe take a look at Bassam's link...

Comment: if you used DateTime.Now.Date instead of DateTime.Now it will work but i don't know why

Comment: Are you using Oracle? This also fails for me when using the Oracle EF provider but it works using the SQL Server provider

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is most likely a problem of the different precisions of the .NET `DateTime` type and the column type you are using in SQL Server - probably `datetime`.

The INSERT statement that is sent to the database with `SaveChanges` looks like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Groups]([GroupDate], [GroupName])
values (@0, @1)
select [GroupId]
from [dbo].[Groups]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [GroupId] = scope_identity() and [GroupDate] = @0',
N'@0 datetime2(7),@1 nvarchar(50)',
@0='2013-09-01 14:21:44.5156250',@1=N'someName'
```

The .NET `DateTime` stores 7 digits after the decimal point: `.5156250`. But the SQL `datetime` type cannot store this because it has less precision and some digits are cut off after storing the value. Hence, the comparison `[GroupDate] = @0` in the `where` clause returns `false` and EF gets the info back that nothing has been stored (although the INSERT actually *has* been performed), cancels the transaction and throws the exception.

As far as I can see you can solve this problem only by one of the following changes:

- Either remove `GroupDate` from the primary key, i.e. make it a non-key column
- Or change the type of the column in SQL Server to `datetime2(7)` which has the same precision as the .NET `DateTime` type
- Or provide your `GroupDate` with less precision so that the value can be stored completely in a SQL `datetime` type without being cut off, for example only with seconds precision and the milliseconds being `0`:

  ```
  var now = DateTime.Now;
  var date = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day,
                          now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);

  var newGroup = new Groups
  {
      GroupDate = date,
      GroupName = "someName"
  };
  ```

  (There might be a smarter way to remove the milliseconds from a given `DateTime` value than the code above, but I couldn't find one right now.)

Comment: I think the better code removing the `milliseconds` part you mentioned may be this: `var date = now.AddMilliseconds(-now.Millisecond);`

Answer (score 1):

Do not switch the **Optmistic Concurrency Updates** off you will hide the problem and not fix it. do the following:

```
using (var db = new MyEntities())
{    
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
    {
        var newGroup = new Groups
        {
            GroupDate = DateTime.Now,
            GroupName = "someName"
        };
        db.Groups.Add(newGroup);
        db.SaveChanges();
        transaction.Complete();
     }
}
```

The different now you are creating the TranscationScope inside the DBContext I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: i tried that but it didn't solve it, this happen even without using a transaction, you can try it

Comment: post the exception call stack please!

Comment: I found this similar to your problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836173/entity-framework-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpec

Comment: it's the same problem with different unknown causes (at least for me)