# Linq not finding matching record that is there

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to find a record that I know exist in the database. When searching for it using this query nothing is found.

```
List<OrganizationALE> ales =
                _ctx.OrganizationALEs.Where(c => c.OrganizationId.Equals(organizationId) && c.LastModified.Equals(modified) && c.StartDate.Equals(start)).ToList();
```

But when I search using this query it is clearly there in the result using watch.
[image]

And if I try pull it out on the very next line using

`var found = ales.First(a => a.LastModified == modified);`

I get an exception say `Sequence contains no matching element`

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the resulting SQL statement and run it manually against the database?

Comment: Yes, it would be good if you can monitor the database session and get the SQL statement generated.

Comment: @DaveSwersky how do I do that?

Comment: @DaveSwersky I figured it out will post above, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet it's because `modified` and/or `start` contains milliseconds that are not stored with the same precision in the database (`datetime` in SQL Server?) so that the comparison fails in the database.

Possible solutions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18558511/270591) (the second and third point apply to your situation). Basically supply less precise `DateTime` values (cut off the millisecond) or use `datetime2(7)` in SQL Server or avoid using equality comparisons with `DateTime` values and use `>=` and `<=` instead.