# Oracle Entity Framework provider doesn't store DateTime.Now with milliseconds

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, datetime

I have basically the exact same question as this guy here.

[why i can't save the current DateTime.Now using Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18557546/why-i-cant-save-the-current-datetime-now-using-entity-framework)

But he was using SQL Server, and I am using Oracle. (My application must work with both)

His problem was that precision wasn't set correctly at the db level.

I've noticed that if I manually edit the milliseconds in my oracle database, EF can pull out the correct timestamp with milliseconds. But when I create an Entity with a DateTime property to "DateTime.Now" it gets truncated.

The DateColumn1 attribute is of the Oracle type `Timestamp`

I logged the insert statement

`insert into "SchemaName"."TableName"("DateColumn1") values (:P0)
--:P0:'5/14/2015 4:07:27 PM' (Type = Date)`

The crazy thing is that this works in SQL Server.

Comment: Is `DateColumn1` a column of type `date` in Oracle?  An Oracle `date` has a time component but only stores time to the second.  You'd need a `timestamp` (or `timestamp with time zone` or `timestamp with local time zone`) to get subsecond precision.

Comment: @JustinCave. Turns out I just needed some extra code in my OnModelCreating() method to tell the Oracle EF provider to treat the column as a Timestamp instead of a Date

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aha! My awesome colleague had an idea and it worked!

In our EF code we tried putting

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<EntityClass>().Property(p => p.TIMESTAMP).HasPrecision(6);
}
```

And then the `DateTime.Now` with milliseconds got stored into the database

### Update - it's worth mentioning how I got in this predicament

### Building the Database with Model First in a "test" application

1. My app has to work with both SQL Server and Oracle. So...
2. I started by designing my database in an EDMX Diagram
3. Once the diagram was done, I generated the DDL for SQL Server.
4. For some reason the Oracle EF provider couldn't generate the DDL so I proceeded to manually make changes to the SQL Server DDL so it would be correct syntactically

   **1st Problem** - my Oracle DDL was using a Date instead of Timestamp. Make sure you use Timestamp!!! DateTime in Oracle doesn't store milliseconds.

### Using Code First from Database for the actual solution

1. I wanted the app to use the Code First approach (Just my preference. I think it's easier to maintain)
2. So I connected to the SQL Server database and generated all of my classes from that schema.
3. I got all of my unit tests passing and then decided to test it with the Oracle database
4. Even after changing from DATE to Timestamp, I was still having problems with the milliseconds going in.
5. I generated another Code First model in a test visual studio solution with a `TIMESTAMP(6)` type in Oracle, except when I looked at the `OnModelCreating` code, it did not generate anything with `HasPrecision(6)` nor were there any decorators on the property in the generated C# POCO class.
6. I noticed if you have the `HasPrecision(6)` code in your `OnModelCreating`, the Code First`CreateDatabase()` will actually make an Oracle `TIMESTAMP(6)`. If you don't, then the Oracle EF provider will use `DATE`

I think if you do the Model First approach you can set precision values in the EDMX diagram, but I've heard that it's bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is to set precision in the configuration class. 
If you have an Entity like this:

```
public class MyEntity
    {
        public DateTime? MyDateTimeWithPrecision{ get; set; }
    }
```

If you use configuration to be added on model builder as following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MyEntityConfiguration());
        }
```

then in your configuration class you can do as following:

```
class MyEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<MyEntity>
    {
        public MyEntityConfiguration()
        {
            Property(e => e.MyDateTimeWithPrecision)
                .HasPrecision(6);
         }
     }
```

With this architectural solution you can have a MyEntityConfiguration class for each entity of your model, so your code should be more readable.

Comment: Up voted. Good idea - I agree this makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add to the above because a bit of this confused me and sent me down the wrong track. The date fields shouldn't use the [TIMESTAMP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.timestampattribute.aspx) annotation as I tried to do. The fields in your POCO class should remain as DateTime:

```
   public class TimeClass
    {
        public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StopTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in on model creating for each of the Date fields in each of your Model Classes you must set the precision of the fields

```
     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MySchema"); //see [here][2]

        modelBuilder.Entity<TimeClass>().Property(p => p.StartTime).HasPrecision(6);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TimeClass>().Property(p => p.StopTime).HasPrecision(6);

    }
```

Then you can get the milliseconds. Time with seconds are recorded by default with the DateTime field

Comment: the TIMESTAMP property in my poco is just the name of the property. the .net type is still DateTime.