# How can I get Entity Framework with Oracle to send fractional seconds to a database in a query?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, datetime

I seem to be having the opposite problem from the asker of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310265/ef6-oracle-timestamp-date)
. I cannot seem to get EF to bind any `DateTime` objects as an Oracle `timestamp` when used as part of a LINQ query. They are being bound as `date` objects, which does not preserve the milliseconds on the `DateTime` object.

In order to get EF to bind `DateTime` objects as `timestamp` variables in insert statements, I needed to heed the advice presented in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248839/oracle-entity-framework-provider-doesnt-store-datetime-now-with-milliseconds). The fix involves modifying `OnModelCreating` to specify the precision of the column. I also added the column type as part of my troubleshooting.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityWithTimestamps>().Property(p => p.NullableTimestampStart)
    .HasColumnType("timestamp")
    .HasPrecision(6);
modelBuilder.Entity<EntityWithTimestamps>().Property(p => p.NullableTimestampEnd)
    .HasColumnType("timestamp")
    .HasPrecision(6);
```

Here is my query:

```
DateTime queryTime = new DateTime(2018, 07, 11, 11, 23, 00, 501);
EntityWithTimestamps ent = Db.TableOfEntitiesWithTimestamps
    .Where(ex => (ex.NullableTimestampStart <= queryTime
        && (ex.NullableTimestampEnd > queryTime || ex.NullableTimestampEnd == null)))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Here is how EF formats the query - it's binding the `queryTime` `DateTime` variable as a `date`. A `date` object will not have sufficient resolution to include fractional seconds. In my opinion, it should be sending my `queryTime` variable over as a `timestamp`.

```
SELECT 
    "Extent1"."STRINGPAYLOAD" AS "STRINGPAYLOAD", 
    "Extent1"."TIMESTAMPSTART" AS "TIMESTAMPSTART", 
    "Extent1"."TIMESTAMPEND" AS "TIMESTAMPEND", 
    "Extent1"."NULLABLETIMESTAMPSTART" AS "NULLABLETIMESTAMPSTART", 
    "Extent1"."NULLABLETIMESTAMPEND" AS "NULLABLETIMESTAMPEND", 
    "Extent1"."TIMESTAMPWITHOUTPRECISION" AS "TIMESTAMPWITHOUTPRECISION"
FROM "SCHEMA_NAME"."TABLE_WITH_TIMESTAMPS" "Extent1"
WHERE (
    ("Extent1"."NULLABLETIMESTAMPSTART" <= :p__linq__0)
    AND (("Extent1"."NULLABLETIMESTAMPEND" > :p__linq__1)
    OR ("Extent1"."NULLABLETIMESTAMPEND" IS NULL)))
    AND (ROWNUM <= (1)
)


-- p__linq__0: '7/11/2018 11:23:00' (Type = Date, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__1: '7/11/2018 11:23:00' (Type = Date, IsNullable = false)
```

I tired using the `DbFunctions.AddMilliseconds` function, and the `DbFunctions.CreateDateTime` function in concert with the `DbFunctions.AddMilliseconds` function. Both these attempts caused exceptions to be thrown due to the improper syntax of the produced queries.

I was able to work around this issue by creating a function in the database that parses a string into a `timestamp`, and then reference it inside the query by using the [EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions) package on NuGet, a predecessor of which was mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310265/ef6-oracle-timestamp-date)
. Note that if the column is nullable, the `DateTime` has to be a `DateTime?`, or it will cast the result of the function to a date.

My database function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DATETIME_TO_TIMESTAMP 
(
  STR IN VARCHAR2 
) RETURN TIMESTAMP AS 
BEGIN
  RETURN to_timestamp(str, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF');
END DATETIME_TO_TIMESTAMP;
```

The corresponding function in C#:

```
class Funcs
{
    [DbFunction("CodeFirstDatabaseSchema", "DATETIME_TO_TIMESTAMP")]
    public static DateTime? Timestamp(string dateTimeToConvert)
    {
        // Implementation not required
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Registering the functions during `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionsConvention<TestDbContext>(schemaName));
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new FunctionsConvention(schemaName, typeof(Funcs)));
```

And, finally, the revised query:

```
string queryTimestamp = queryTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFFFFFF");
EntityWithTimestamps ent = Db.TableOfEntitiesWithTimestamps
    .Where(ex => (
           (ex.NullableTimestampStart <= Funcs.Timestamp(queryTimestamp)
           && (ex.NullableTimestampEnd > Funcs.Timestamp(queryTimestamp) 
           || (ex.NullableTimestampEnd == null)
        )
    ).FirstOrDefault();
```

I feel as though this is a bit more complex than it needs to be. Does anyone know of a better way to get Oracle EF to use a `timestamp` value in LINQ queries?

I also tried modifying my application's `app.config` file. `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` actually allows some control of how numbers get mapped from .NET objects to Oracle types and the precision of those Oracle typed. [This is accomplished in the EdmMappings section of the configuration file.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E85694_01/ODPNT/entityDataTypeMapping.htm#ODPNT8300) Unfortunately, in my attempts, specifying that `DateTime` .NET objects should be mapped to `timestamp` objects of a particular precision in Oracle did not have any effect.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_It_IEFL7YzA2tpTfME2uwzhiqizprZI) is a link to a solution that runs through all of my examples.