# "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dbcontext

I'm using EF in order to insert simple object into db:

```
public bool AddQuestion(Question question)
{
    try
    {
        _ctx.Questions.Add(question);

        _ctx.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

my DbContext look like:

```
 public class AnyContext:DbContext
 {
    public AnyContext():base()
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AnyContext, AnyContextMigrationConfiguration>());
    }
    public AnyContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
         Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
         Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

         Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AnyContext, AnyContextMigrationConfiguration>());
    }
     public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
 }
```

And POCO look like:

```
[Table("Questions")]
public class Question
{
    public int Id  { get; set; }
    public String body { get; set; }
    public String img_path { get; set; }
    public int location { get; set; }
    public int status { get; set; }
    public DateTime ask_date { get; set; }

}
```

And I get **"Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). **  every time

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong here. Is this the exact code that causes the exception?

Comment: Exact code! I'm using azure SQL

Comment: Where is _ctx defined?

Comment: AnyContext type that inherent from dbContext

Comment: Yes, but it looks like AnyContact has 2 constructors.  One that is empty and one that takes a string.  The empty constructor does not call base DBContext, while the string constructor does.  My guess is this is your problem.  Can you modify AnyContext() to AnyContext() : base()?  Edited: Come to think of it, AnyContext() is missing a lot of stuff that AnyContext(string connectionString) has.

Comment: See my edited DbContext it as you suggest but still the same issue

Comment: Have you seen this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836173/

Comment: @AaronPalmer - Yes I read it but it is not seems to be relevant to my case . I send one request through REST