# Insert/Update/Delete on GridView generated by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

I'm using EF 6.1.3 and SQL server 2014 for this ASP.NET Web Forms application. I drag&dropped a gridview on my .aspx page design view and used Smart Tag to choose my data source and automatically fill the grid. I enabled edit and delete operations on gridview and it works with no problem but I want it to use the functions I wrote.

This is what I tried for delete operation

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
            {
                    int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                    Result<Models.UserList> result;
                    using (ModelOperations.UserList.IUserListOperations dao = new ModelOperations.UserList.UserListOperations())
                    {
                        result = dao.removeUser(new Models.UserList()
                        {
                            ID = Convert.ToInt32((GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Text))
                        });
                    }
            }
        }
```

It actually works but the page gives an error. The method in my UserListOperations have a try-catch block but there is no exception caught because the code is simply working.

This is the GridView code generated by EF

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="UserID" DataSourceID="myEntities">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="UserID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="UserName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserPW" HeaderText="UserPW" SortExpression="UserPW" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="UserType" HeaderText="UserType" SortExpression="UserType" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And this is the error

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

If I take the values from textbox and send values that way, there is no error so I'm guessing it's something about the auto-generated grid.

Comment: if you check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836173/entity-framework-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpec  you can have more informations about your problem i think

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did check that link but didn't/couldn't find an answer for my problem. In my case the delete operation works and I still get this error that is what I'm trying to understand why that happens.