# Multiple problems when deleting from a database

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to remove an object from my sql database. I have been using this same method in multiple places and they all work fine except for here.

My Code:

```
foreach (TestCase testCase in testCaseList)
        {
            db.TestCases.Remove(testCase);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

The error that I get from this code is: "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager"

I found a solution to this problem which was adding an attach. The resulting code was:

```
foreach (TestCase testCase in testCaseList) 
    {
        db.TestCases.Attach(testCase);
        db.TestCases.Remove(testCase);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    {
```

With this code, I get the following error: "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows(0)." I found some information on this error, but nothing that seemed to apply to my issue. Is there a specific reason these issues are arising and what can I do to solve the errors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework: "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836173/entity-framework-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpec)

Comment: Are you aware of how this could be caused?

Comment: Never-mind, I was accidentally removing it twice. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My issue resulted from the fact that I was actually removing the entity twice. For anybody that gets similar errors in the future, be sure to double check your code for duplicate statements.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @SruitA.Suk I saw this as a complete answer. My issue resulted from not seeing that I duplicated code and the answer for people seeing similar issues is to double check your code.