# Entity Framework 6: Insert or Update

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to insert or update a row in a table with Entity Framework depending if the primary key (string) already exists in the table.

I am using the following code to do that which I got from here: [Insert or update pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx#Insert%20or%20update%20pattern)

```
private void InsertOrUpdate(ServiceMonitoring sm)
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new MyDBEntities())
        {
            context.Entry(sm).State = sm.serviceName == null ?
                EntityState.Added :
                EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        log.Info("ServiceMonitoring updated");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("Error updating ServiceMonitoring");
        log.Debug(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

It is working fine when the row (e.g. serviceName = "MyService") already exists. Then an UPDATE is performed. But if the row does not exist, the INSERT fails and I get the following error message:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836173/entity-framework-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpec?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I don't think that this explains my issue. I am running this in our test system which is used rarely. Also, I have changed the "serviceName" to some weird random character sequence which will never show up in this table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the update or insert pattern works with the primary key in the MSDN sample is because it is flagged as an `Identity` field. When you add an entity to a DbContext, EF gives the Id field a default value of 0, and the database will assign a unique value to the row when the `INSERT` is executed.

You've tried to incorrectly adapt the 'update or insert' pattern to use the property `serviceName`, and the solution is to use the pattern as provided by the MSDN article you referenced, or execute a query.

For completeness, WHY doesn't your adaption work?
Because you are passing in a `ServiceMonitoring` object and expecting `context.Entry(sm)` to query your database for the correct row of data. It does not sir. So in your case, `EntityState.Added` is basically unreachable code.

```
private void InsertOrUpdate(ServiceMonitoring sm)  
{
    try
    {
        //this brand new DbContext instance has not queried your database, and is not tracking any objects!
        using (var context = new MyDBEntities())  
        {
            //if (sm.serviceName is null) <- should never be null, as it's the ServiceMonitoring object you are passing into the function.
            //The DbContext.Entry() does not know whether or not this actually exists in the database, it only allows you to inform
            //EF about the state of the object.
            context.Entry(sm).State = sm.serviceName == null ?  //<- Always false (unless you *really* want a serviceName to not have a name)
                EntityState.Added : // <- code unreachable
                EntityState.Modified; //This is where the exception occurs, your code is always generating an UPDATE statement.
                                        //When the entry exists in the database, EF's generated UPDATE statement succeeds.
                                        //When the entry does not exist, the UPDATE statement fails.
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        log.Info("ServiceMonitoring updated");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("Error updating ServiceMonitoring");
        log.Debug(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand what you explained and will try to optimize my code accordingly. The only thing I don't agree with is the following: "EF knows not to fill in the primary key on the insert statement because it will be auto-generated by the database" The primary key is not auto-generated by the database since it's not an IDENTITY column. The primary key is simply the serviceName column which I will fill with a unique string for each service I want to monitor in that table.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You are correct, and I have adjusted my answer.

Comment: Accepted the answer after 3 years, lol. Better late then never eh?

Comment: Yep, I reviewed all my questions today, and found that I did not accept this pretty neat answer. Thanks again!