# Entity framework update related entities without concurrency conflict

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, optimistic-concurrency

I have two related entities: User and UserProfile.  A user can have many profiles (settings).  I want to be able to update them together, but I am currently getting concurrency error when i do so:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

This is my code to update:

```
public void UpdateUser(UserList user, int timeoutMins)
{
    using (var ctx = GetCodingContext())
    {
        try
        {
            ctx.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            CR_USER_PROFILE timeoutProfile = GetTimeoutUserProfile(user.UserGUID);
            if (timeoutProfile != null && !timeoutProfile.PROFILE_VALUE.Equals(timeoutMins.ToString()))
            {
                timeoutProfile.PROFILE_VALUE = timeoutMins.ToString();
                UpdateUserProfile(timeoutProfile,ctx);
            }
            else if(timeoutProfile == null && timeoutMins > 0)
            {
                var timeoutKey = FFCEnumerations.Profiles.Keys.Timeout.GetStringValue();
                AddUserProfile(user, timeoutKey, timeoutMins.ToString(), ctx);
            }
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error occurred updating user " + ex);
        }
    }
}

public void UpdateUserProfile(CR_USER_PROFILE profile, CodingContext ctx)
{
    try
    {
        ctx.Entry(profile).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error occurred updating User Profile");
    }
}

public CR_USER_PROFILE GetTimeoutUserProfile(Guid userGuid)
{
    using (var ctx = GetCodingContext())
    {
        var timeoutKey = FFCEnumerations.Profiles.Keys.Timeout.GetStringValue();
        var profileList = ctx.CR_USER_PROFILE.Where(p => p.UserGUID == userGuid && p.PROFILE_TYPE_CD == timeoutKey);
        return profileList.SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

It works well when I add both entities, but not when updating.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is where there's a lot of discussion on this problem - [Entity Framework: "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836173/entity-framework-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpec?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I was using a different context for fetching the profile I wanted to update.  This was causing the concurrency conflict because EF thought this entity was being changed somewhere else (another context).  So, I created an overload for this method so I can pass the context as an argument and fetch the entity with the same context I was going to update it with.

```
public CR_USER_PROFILE GetTimeoutUserProfile(Guid userGuid, CodingContext ctx)
{
    var timeoutKey = FFCEnumerations.Profiles.Keys.Timeout.GetStringValue();
    var profileList = ctx.CR_USER_PROFILE.Where(p => p.UserGUID == userGuid && p.PROFILE_TYPE_CD == timeoutKey);
    return profileList.SingleOrDefault();
}
```