# EF6 throws concurrency exception when trying to add new entry with identity column

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I'm generating entity models from my database with EF6. I created two test tables. One table has an Identity column, and the other table doesn't. Here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestNoIdentity] 
(
    [ID]      INT          NOT NULL,
    [DTStamp] DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    [Note]    VARCHAR(255) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC, [DTStamp] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestIdentity] 
(
    [ID]      INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [DTStamp] DATETIME     NOT NULL,
    [Note]    VARCHAR(255) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC, [DTStamp] ASC)
);
```

Test code:

```
using (TestEntities entities = new TestEntities())
{
    // This works
    var entry1 = new TestNoIdentity();
    entry1.ID = 1;
    entry1.DTStamp = DateTime.Now;
    entry1.Note = "No Identity";
    entities.TestNoIdentity.Add(entry1);
    entities.SaveChanges();

    // This doesn't work
    var entry2 = new TestIdentity();
    entry2.DTStamp = DateTime.Now;
    entities.TestIdentity.Add(entry2);
    entities.SaveChanges();     //optimistic concurrency exception
    
    // This query works
    // entities.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestIdentity] ([DTStamp]) VALUES ('1/1/2021 12:00:00 PM')");
    
    return entities.ID.ToString();
}
```

Why is it throwing a concurrency exception? There are no other users or duplicated instances of the entity.

The message from the exception:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

Comment: Please check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836173/entity-framework-store-update-insert-or-delete-statement-affected-an-unexpec

Comment: @José Polanco Hi, I have checked that post and several other related threads. I can update the table with DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(), and the other table with the same properties except for the identity column can be updated without issues. I can't figure out the reason why it is throwing the concurrency exception when there is no other code modifying the entities/database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without IDENTITY EF doesn't have to fetch back the ID, and that's where it's failing.  You've got a DATETIME column in your PK, and DATETIME only has precision of about 3ms, so comparing the stored value with the generated value may fail.  Change it to `DATETIME2` to better match the precision of .NET's DateTime, or trim your .NET DateTime to the nearest second.

Comment: Thank you. That solves the problem. I switched the DTstamp to a string and it works.