Error while deleting the record using ASP.NET MVC
I created a CRUD operation and in that, I get an error while trying to delete a record:

Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

I created this action method for deleting a record:
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(tblMember objMember)
{
    _memberContext.Entry(objMember).State = EntityState.Deleted;

    int a = _memberContext.SaveChanges();

    if (a > 0)
    {
        TempData["DeleteMessage"] = "<script>alert('Data Deleted')</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["DeleteMessage"] = "<script>alert('Data Not Deleted')</script>";
    } 

    return RedirectToAction("MemberList");
}


Why not just use _memberContext.tblMemberSet.Remove(objMember); ? I just guessed that the DbSet<tblMember> is called tblMemberSet - adjust as needed. But I would just call the .Remove() method on the DbSet instead of using the EntityState directly ...

When i used this method, The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.
this error comes.

We need to see how you define your entity, especially do you have the proper attributes like [Key] etc. also worth to check the sql code generated by EF.

From the error message I guess you are trying to a delete a record with Entity Framework.
My experience is that the most common reason for that is when trying to delete a record with an ID that doesn't exists in the database.
Make sure that you are sending a record with a valid ID that exists in the database.

Yes Dear, the ID is exits in database and update command working perfectly, there is only issue in delete command only. When I clicked on delete option, the details also shown of that id but after that when I clicked on delete button, this error comes.

It is not sure that the problem lies in the Delete method you provided.
I recommend you to write a unit test against this method and see if it works then, to be sure that the error is not outside of this method.

There are also some good answers in a previous question that you can look into and try out. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1836173

Make sure that the objMember object is not detached. If the object is not detached first find the object in the database and then try the delete operation again
