# Ignore milliseconds when comparing two datetimes

Tags: c#, datetime, c#-4.0

I am comparing the LastWriteTime of two files, however it is always failing because the file I downloaded off the net always has milliseconds set at 0, and my original file has an actual value. Is there a simple way to ignore the milliseconds when comparing?

Here's my function:

```
//compare file's dates
public bool CompareByModifiedDate(string strOrigFile, string strDownloadedFile)
{
     DateTime dtOrig = File.GetLastWriteTime(strOrigFile);
     DateTime dtNew = File.GetLastWriteTime(strDownloadedFile);
            
     if (dtOrig == dtNew)
        return true;
     else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: [How to truncate milliseconds off of a .NET DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004698/)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Create a new DateTime value with the milliseconds component set to 0:

```
dt = dt.AddMilliseconds(-dt.Millisecond);
```

Comment: Warning: this won't work when the `DateTime` has non-zero microseconds. See @PeterIvan's or @DeanChalk's answers.

Answer (score 127):

I recommend you use an extension method:

```
public static DateTime TrimMilliseconds(this DateTime dt)
{
    return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second, 0, dt.Kind);
}
```

then its just:

```
if (dtOrig.TrimMilliseconds() == dtNew.TrimMilliseconds())
```

Comment: Perhaps preserve the `DateTimeKind` as well by adding `dt.Kind` to end of ctor

Comment: return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second, 0, dt.Kind);

Answer (score 58):

Care should be taken, if `dt` has **non-zero microseconds** (fractions of millis). Setting only milliseconds to zero is not enough.
To set millis and below to zero (and get a succesfull comparison), the code would be:

```
dt = dt.AddTicks(-dt.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond); // TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond=10000000
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Fast, and preserves `dt.Kind`. I know it gives the same in all cases, but to me it is more natural to use `dt = dt.AddTicks(-(dt.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond));`, i.e. use `%` operator first, and then negate. That is because the behavior of `%` with a negative first operand seems a bit confusing to me, so I prefer my version where `%` operates on two positive operands.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Your code is exactly the same as mine. According to operator precedence, you multiply and/or divide and just then add/negate. So the parentheses change nothing, just clarify the well-established logic.

Comment: No that is incorrect. In rare cases (that cannot occur in your use above, so your use is fine), there is a difference. Consider this code (where `a` and `b` must not be declared `const`): `long a = long.MinValue; long b = 10L; long x = (-a) % b; long y = -(a % b); long z = -a % b;` Here the value of `x` will be negative, because negation of `a` gives `a` again, and a negative value `%`-ed on a positive value gives a negative value. But the value of `y` is positive, because this time we negate a negative result between `-10` and `0`, and that gives a positive number. Now check `z` to see it!

Answer (score 34):

```
TimeSpan difference = dtNew - dtOrig;
if (difference >= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go IMHO.

Answer (score 18):

You can subtract them, to get a `TimeSpan`.

Then use `TimeSpan.totalSeconds()`

Answer (score 8):

This is overkill for a single Truncate, but if you have several and of various types you could do this using the generalized Extension Method below:

```
DateTime dtSecs = DateTime.Now.TruncateTo(Extensions.DateTruncate.Second);
DateTime dtHrs  = DateTime.Now.TruncateTo(Extensions.DateTruncate.Hour);
```

More general Use Extension method:

```
    public static DateTime TruncateTo(this DateTime dt, DateTruncate TruncateTo)
    {
        if (TruncateTo == DateTruncate.Year)
            return new DateTime(dt.Year, 0, 0);
        else if (TruncateTo == DateTruncate.Month)
            return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 0);
        else if (TruncateTo == DateTruncate.Day)
            return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day);
        else if (TruncateTo == DateTruncate.Hour)
            return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, 0, 0);
        else if (TruncateTo == DateTruncate.Minute)
            return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, 0);
        else 
            return new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second);

    }
    public enum DateTruncate
    {
        Year,
        Month,
        Day,
        Hour,
        Minute,
        Second
    }
```

Comment: With Peter Ivan's solution, it is natural to just do `public static DateTime TruncateTo(this DateTime dt, long truncateResolution) { return dt.AddTicks(-(dt.Ticks % truncateResolution)); }`. Much shorter and clearer. Then use like this: `DateTime dtSecs = DateTime.Now.TruncateTo(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond);
DateTime dtHrs  = DateTime.Now.TruncateTo(TimeSpan.TicksPerHour);` and so on. You can even truncate to more strange resolutions, like multiples of 3 hours (`3 * TimeSpan.TicksPerHour`).

Comment: The dt.Kind should be set for each new DateTime

Answer (score 5):

Here is the simplest way of doing this. You can control `precision` as you want.

```cs
bool AreEqual(DateTime a, DateTime b, TimeSpan precision)
{
    return Math.Abs((a - b).TotalMilliseconds) < precision.TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

and usage is pretty self-explanatory

```cs
var _ = AreEqual(a, b, precision: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to create new dates, inputting the year, month, day, hour, minute, second into the constructor. Alternatively, you could simply compare each value separately.

Answer (score 3):

instead of trimming unrelevant DateTime parts via creating new `DateTime`s, compare only *relevant* parts:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool CompareWith(this DateTime dt1, DateTime dt2)
    {
        return
            dt1.Second == dt2.Second && // 1 of 60 match chance
            dt1.Minute == dt2.Minute && // 1 of 60 chance
            dt1.Day == dt2.Day &&       // 1 of 28-31 chance
            dt1.Hour == dt2.Hour &&     // 1 of 24 chance
            dt1.Month == dt2.Month &&   // 1 of 12 chance
            dt1.Year == dt2.Year;       // depends on dataset
    }
}
```

I took [answer by Dean Chalk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7029046/1506454) as base for performance comparison, and results are:

- `CompareWith` is a bit faster than `TrimMilliseconds` in case of equal dates
- `CompareWith` is a faster than dates are not equal

my perf test (run in Console project)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dtOrig = new DateTime(2018, 03, 1, 10, 10, 10);
    var dtNew = dtOrig.AddMilliseconds(100);

    //// perf run for not-equal dates comparison
    //dtNew = dtNew.AddDays(1);
    //dtNew = dtNew.AddMinutes(1);

    int N = 1000000;

    bool isEqual = false;

    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        // TrimMilliseconds comes from 
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/7029046/1506454 
        // answer by Dean Chalk
        isEqual = dtOrig.TrimMilliseconds() == dtNew.TrimMilliseconds();
    }
    var ms = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    Console.WriteLine("DateTime trim: " + ms + " ms");

    sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        isEqual = dtOrig.CompareWith(dtNew);
    }
    ms = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    Console.WriteLine("DateTime partial compare: " + ms + " ms");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ether set the milliseconds in your other datetime to zero, or subtract one date from the other and just check the `TotalMinutes` property of the resulting time span.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an extension method that would set the milliseconds to zero for a DateTime object

```
public static DateTime ZeroMilliseconds(this DateTime value) {
  return new DateTime(value.Year, value.Month, value.Day, 
    value.Hours, value.Minutes, value.Seconds);
}
```

Then in your function

```
 if (dtOrig.ZeroMilliseconds() == dtNew.ZeroMilliseconds())
        return true;
     else
        return false;
```

Comment: So your method returns a DateTime but is defined as returning a string.

Comment: I don't know why all programmers needs too many lines when rteurning a bool function with

Comment: The value.Kind should be set in new DateTime

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use datetime format with the format you want, and convert it again to datetime as below,

```
//compare file's dates
        
        String format1 = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"; // you also can avoid seconds if you want

        public bool CompareByModifiedDate(string strOrigFile, string strDownloadedFile)
        {
            
            //.here we will use the format

            DateTime dtOrig = Convert.ToDateTime(File.GetLastWriteTime(strOrigFile).ToString(format1));
            DateTime dtNew = Convert.ToDateTime(File.GetLastWriteTime(strDownloadedFile).ToString(format1));

            if (dtOrig == dtNew)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

cast sortable strings and compare. simple and run well.

```
    return string.Compare(dtOrig.ToString("s"), dtNew.ToString("s"), 
StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0;
```

Answer (score -3):

The most straightforward way to truncate time is to format it and parse on the units that you want:

```
var myDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
```

DOK's method re-written

```
public bool CompareByModifiedDate(string strOrigFile, string strDownloadedFile)
    {
         DateTime dtOrig = DateTime.Parse(File.GetLastWriteTime(strOrigFile).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
         DateTime dtNew = DateTime.Parse(File.GetLastWriteTime(strDownloadedFile).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));

         if (dtOrig == dtNew)
            return true;
         else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Run your code in the UK, Europe or Australia and see what happens. I'm not a fan of this approact anyway, but you need to be using an invariant culture or `DateTime.ParseExact` for this to be even remotely reliable.

Answer (score -6):

Don't know why almost all programmers needs extra lines to return a bool value from a function with a bool expression.

instead

```
if (dtOrig.ZeroMilliseconds() == dtNew.ZeroMilliseconds())
    return true;
 else
    return false;
```

you can always just use

```
return dtOrig.ZeroMilliseconds() == dtNew.ZeroMilliseconds()
```

if the expression is true it returns true else false.

Comment: where did you get ZeroMilliseconds() from?