# Inserting a date/time value in Access using an OleDbParameter

Tags: c#, ms-access, parameters, oledb

I'm trying to do an insert in oledb(ms access database)
the field called objectdate is date/time

the code i use to add the parameter is this, but i'm getting error.

```
  OleDbParameter objectdate = new OleDbParameter("@objectdate", OleDbType.DBDate);
  objectdate.Value = DateTime.Now; cmd.Parameters.Add(objectdate);
```

the error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Please don't put " c#" at the end of your title. On [so], we use tags for that.

Comment: I just copied and pasted those exact statements into C# (VS 2010) and they worked fine for me. Voting to close as **"off-topic (...problem that can no longer be reproduced...)"**.

Answer (score 10):

OleDB doesn't like milliseconds in the datetime parameters. If you remove the milliseconds it will go ok. See also: [How to truncate milliseconds off of a .NET DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004698/how-to-truncate-milliseconds-off-of-a-net-datetime/1005222#1005222).

Comment: [How to truncate milliseconds off of a .NET DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1005222)

Answer (score 0):

You could use.

```
   OleDbParameter objectdate = new OleDbParameter("@objectdate", DbType.DateTime);
   objectdate.Value = DateTime.Now; cmd.Parameters.Add(objectdate);
```

or use the Ole Automation version of the date.

```
OleDbParameter objectdate = new OleDbParameter("@objectdate", DbType.DateTime);
       objectdate.Value = DateTime.Now.ToOADate(); cmd.Parameters.Add(objectdate);
```

Or you could enter the datetime as a literal since the Datetime.ToString() removes the milliseconds that access can't work with.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objectdate", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

this should work.

Comment: doesn't work, it say 
Failed to convert parameter value from a DbType to a DateTime.

Comment: @robert .. could you post the code you used? just in the comments here.

Comment: @robert i wanted you to replace OleDbType.DBDate with DbType.DateTime

Comment: the code and the error I'm getting:    
    


DateTime dateobjectdate = DateTime.Now;

 OleDbParameter objectdate = new OleDbParameter("@objectdate", DbType.DateTime);
                objectdate.Value = dateobjectdate; cmd.Parameters.Add(objectdate);


Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Also i've tried the next lines with no luck, btw how can indent??
__________________________________________________________________
OleDbParameter objectdate = new OleDbParameter("@objectdate", OleDbType.Date);
                objectdate.Value = DateTime.Now; cmd.Parameters.Add(objectdate);

________________________________
Data type mismatch in criteria expression.


    OleDbParameter objectdate = new OleDbParameter("@objectdate", DbType.DateTime);
                objectdate.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString(); cmd.Parameters.Add(objectdate);
Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: @robert this seems to be a known issue. could you try using DbType.Date ? just to see if it works.

Comment: @robert i've added other samples that should work. please try them out.

Comment: i tested the 3 method, and still i'm getting the:
Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

the access field is datetime, i don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: @robert why don't you just call the Date() function in your sql? access understands that.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence:

```
OleDbParameter objectdate = new OleDbParameter("@objectdate", DbType.DateTime);
```

is not acepted in visual basic 2008, I use like this:

```
ordeen.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("objectdate", DbType.DateTime))
ordeen.Parameters("objectdate").Value=object.text   'but its not run
```

the next sentence only functional in sqlserver:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objectdate", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

the problem in Access continued yet

Answer (score 0):

When using `OleDb` in `.netstandard2.0` you can add using the `.AddWithValue` with just a key value pair. The type is inferred from the `value` object:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@objectdate", DateTime.Now)
```

Do not convert to string because that would destroy the ability to infer type.