# Passing DateTime.Now into Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am facing a problem on passing the `DateTime.`Now into Access database:

```
oleDBCommand.CommandText =
  "INSERT INTO tblData "([PIC], [Sampling Date]) "VALUES (@PIC, @SamplingDate)";

oleDBCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@PIC", combobox1.Text));
oleDBCommand.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@SamplingDate", DateTime.Now));
```

I tried a lot of methods from the internet like using `oleDBType.Date`, `DateTime.Now.ToString()`, using `AddWithValue.....` And none of it is working.

**Note 1:** Database setting `[Sampling Date] = Data Type: Date/Time (Format - Long Time)`, database was

**Note 2**: Below code was working but I prefer to using .parameters as it look much more organize and easy to manage.

```
oleDBCommand.CommandText =
 "INSERT INTO tblData ([PIC], [Sampling Date]) " VALUES ('" + combobox1.Text + "', '" + DateTime.Now + "')";
```

Comment: Related : http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/660282/Date-Format-in-Select-Query-With-Csharp-To-MS-Acce

Comment: Tested the solution on suggested webpage, it is not working as well

Comment: `DateTime.Now` gets "local" time (problematic for a couple of reasons), are you sure you don't want to explicitly get UTC (`DateTime.UtcNow`)?  Also, what do you mean by "not working"?  Throws an exception (which one)?  Puts in the wrong data (what data)?

Comment: Try with DateTime.UtcNow and it is not working. Not Work with description (Data type mismatch in criteria expression). In my code, my intention of the [Sampling Date] was whenever person-in-charge collect the sample, they will key in their name and the [Sampling Date] will auto generate base on that day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting a date/time value in Access using an OleDbParameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522924/inserting-a-date-time-value-in-access-using-an-oledbparameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to pass parameter when specifying current date.

Let the ms access sql query handle it, you need to replace `@SamplingDate` parameter to `Date()` for example

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblData ([PIC], [Sampling Date]) VALUES (@PIC, Date())";
```

Here is the best explanation [Insert today's date](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-today-s-date-ff6c27e8-8a35-4a15-b053-39fb03778904)

Comment: Maybe.  If the database has a different setting than the client, this may produce wrong results.

Comment: No, I mean if the database is set to a different timezone (perhaps if the database is on another machine, somewhere else)

Comment: ok that's probably will result a different time input? i will consider that

Comment: @user6648485 i found another solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217464/trying-to-insert-datetime-now-into-date-time-field-gives-data-type-mismatch-er this will clearly explain the error.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this this week and the accepted answer really did not help me. I found that if I did the assignment of the date+time as an ODBC canonical string (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss), it worked just fine. So, my C# code looked something like:

```
InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + column.ColumnName, OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("u");
```

for the first row and then

```
InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + column.ColumnName).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("u")
```

for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This,**

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblData ([PIC], [Sampling Date]) VALUES (@PIC, @SamplingDate)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PIC",OleDbType.VarChar).Value = combobox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@PIC", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [ms-access](/questions/tagged/ms-access)

Comment: The idea was not working as it show (Data type mismatch in criteria expression).