# Select records of last 12hours vb.net/MS ACCESS

Tags: vb.net

I am vb.net newbie and working on a program which will be used as a daily-worklog. As backend I use MS ACCESS. I store  the "datetime.utc.now" time in a field (type:date/time) of MS Access.

This is shown in the database like: dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss

I want to see all entered items of the last 12 hours. I used many different ways, but I´m not able to fix it.

My preferred / logical (for me :-)) way to do this was:

1. add the parameter:

   ```
   mycommand.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("date12",OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-12)
   ```
2. Query the database

   ```
   select * from complaints where entrydate >= @date12;
   ```

But I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

> Failure message = "data types in criteria expression incompatible"

I assume the problem is the different time formats, but I'm not sure and I have no clue how I could fix it.

Comment: Did you try to create a parameter of type DateTime instead of DbTimeStamp?

Comment: Unfortunately datetime is not available when i usw oledbtype. Only date or time is available.

Answer (score 1):

MS Access does not use named parameters. You use a `?` for all of the placeholders in the SQL statement. You still can and should give the parameter object a name, but the value is matched to the placeholder based on position in the Parameters collection and query string rather than name.

SQL:

```
"select * from complaints where entrydate >= ?;"
```

VB:

```
mycommand.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("date12",OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-12)
```

Do ***NOT*** settle for hard-coding the parameter value. What you can do is use SQL expressions to determine the date value, and avoid both parameters and string concatentation:

```sql
 select * from complaints where entrydate >= DATEADD('h', -12, Now())
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for all of your tips. But as far as i unterstood  your comment correctly that i should use expressions  I have to have one command for each. E.g. if I wanna see the last 12 hours and 3,6,9 months, I need 4 commands. I thought if I use parameters, then I only change the parameter value and could use only 1 command. As I mentioned above I'm a newbie and the www. gives way to much different ways of how to do a certain step and I thought the parameterized one is the most elegant and safest one (injection). I appreciate any help u give!!! Thanks a lot

Comment: Using parameters is fine. Showing the DATEADD() version is just there to show the other alternative to concatenating data into the string.

Comment: i used     "mycommand.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("date12", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-0.5)" but it Returns not exactly the last 12 hours. it Returns up to 12:00:00 of the previous day from now. it´s blowing my mind

Answer (score -1):

You can change the type to `OleDbType.Date` or hardcode the query:

```
select * from complaints where entrydate >= ( Now() - 0.5 )
```

[Trouble inserting DateTime into Access with OleDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527958/trouble-inserting-datetime-into-access-with-oledb)

---

As a side note, most [value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/value-types-and-reference-types) are generally safe to hardcode:

```
"select * from complaints where entrydate >= " & DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-12).ToOADate()
```

Comment: THX for your answer: does 0.5 mean 12 hours i guess, but what if i wanna make the date flexible!?!? E.g.: 12 hours, 3,6,9 months!?

Comment: @Aeronaut Yes, DateTime in Office is generally stored in number of days since 1/0/1900. You can try the `OleDbType.Date` parameter type for dynamic date.

Comment: when i use:                    mycommand.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("date12", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-0.5)
then it Returns Dates up to 17.01.2018 11:45:00 ????  has anyody an idea how i can fix this issue!?!?!

Comment: `.Date` not `.DBDate`