# Updating images using upload file in ASP.MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I have 30 images and next to them there is a upload button.

When you select new image and press update, it should delete the old image and save the new image with the same name and path.

I do this with:

```
string path = "~/Pics/Image1.jpg";
System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(path));
uploadfile.SaveAs(path);
```

It works,i can see the change in my folder where i keep all of my images, but in the browser i see the old image and i need to delete my cache in order to see the new image.

Is there any way i can update my images and show the new images without deleting cache from the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a browser caching issue as you suspect. What you can do is add a query string value or something along those lines so that the browser will have to reload the file.

The end result would be `image.jpg?image=randomNumber`

I usually do this through javascript and you can use [generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range) to help you figure that out.

Now just as a note you are only adding the querystring to the source of the image tag just in case I was not clear.

Answer (score 3):

You need change http header `Last-Modified`  to browser identify change image and download new image. Your response apparently is correct.

```
var headerValue = Request.Headers['If-Modified-Since'];
if (headerValue != null)
{
    var modifiedSince = DateTime.Parse(headerValue).ToLocalTime();
    // Insert date of your file change
    if (modifiedSince >= dateOfFileChanged)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(304, "Page has not been modified");
    }
}

// page has been changed.
// generate a view ...

// .. and set last modified in the date format specified in the HTTP rfc.
Response.AddHeader('Last-Modified', dateOfFileChanged.
                                ToUniversalTime().ToString("R"));
```

This code is extracted from this question [Last-Modified Header in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498135/last-modified-header-in-mvc) .

Comment: A proper HTTP caching mechanism is definitly better than using a random number in the URL. Got my vote.