# How to clear cache in specified controller in asp mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically clear outputcache for controller action method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167890/how-to-programmatically-clear-outputcache-for-controller-action-method)

How to clear cache in specified controller?

I try to use several approaches:

```
Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem();
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
```

There is no any effect, it not work. :(
May be exists any way to get all keys in controller cache and remove they explicitly?
And in which overridden method i should perform clear cache? and how to do that?

Does any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

put this on your Model:

```
public class NoCache : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and on your specific controller:
e.g:

```
[NoCache]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Home()
 {
     ////////...
}
```

source: [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160105/asp-net-mvc-disable-browser-cache?rq=1)

Comment: That works but not immediately, need to wait when last cache to expire.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult DontCacheMeIfYouCan()
{

}
```

If this doesn't do it for you then a custom attribute like Mark Yu suggests.

Comment: This worked for me in my scenario... Thankyou Very Much..

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
public void ClearApplicationCache()
{
    List<string> keys = new List<string>();

    // retrieve application Cache enumerator
    IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = Cache.GetEnumerator(); 

    // copy all keys that currently exist in Cache
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        keys.Add(enumerator.Key.ToString());
    }

    // delete every key from cache
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
    {
        Cache.Remove(keys[i]);
    }
}
```