# Filter a DataTable using DateTime value

Tags: c#

Updated:

I am trying to filter a DataTable based on a particular date.
My datatable has a column "whn" which contains dates. A Sample date from the DataTable:

```
{21/02/2012 10:03:53}   object {System.DateTime}
```

Here is the code I am using to try and filter the DataTable:

```
 String datevalue= "21/02/2012 10:03:53";

  DataRow[] foundRows;
  foundRows = dttemp.Select(String.Format("whn = '{0}'", datevalue));
```

However this does not work and returns 0 rows. Even though I know that a row containing the date in "datevalue" exists.

Unsure why this is not working, any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to exactly match the supplied DateTime, including fractions of a second, you should use a DateTime format that has enough precision.  Probably the round-trip format ("o") is a good bet:

```
foundRows = dttemp.Select(String.Format(dttemp.Locale, "whn = '{0:o}'", datevalue));
```

However, it's more likely you want to match values that fall into a range.  For example, if you want all values that have the same date, but any time of day, you could use:

```
foundRows = dttemp.Select(String.Format(dttemp.Locale, "whn >='{0:o}' AND whn < '{1:o}'",
      datevalue.Date, datevalue.AddDays(1).Date));
```

Similarly if you want all values that are in the same second (but may have fractions of a second), you can use:

```
DateTime from = dttemp.AddTicks( - (dttemp.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond));
foundRows = dttemp.Select(String.Format(dttemp.Locale, "whn >='{0:o}' AND whn < '{1:o}'",
      from, from.AddSeconds(1)));
```

The call to AddTicks truncates the supplied DateTime to a whole number of seconds, as described in the accepted answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004698/how-to-truncate-milliseconds-off-of-a-net-datetime/1005222#1005222).

Note I used `dttemp.Locale` to use the correct locale (CultureInfo) in case your DataTable has a locale other than your current culture.

Comment: Thanks, really helpful response. Getting an error though :

`A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Comment: Ah nevermind, managed to get it working. Thanks for the help!

Fixed my problem by parsing my string to DateTime.

`DateTime test_time = DateTime.Parse(datevalue);`

Answer (score 2):

`foundRows = dttemp.Select("whn LIKE '{0}'",datevalue);`

should probably be

`foundRows = dttemp.Select(String.Format("whn LIKE '{0}'",datevalue));`

more info here http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

Comment: Thanks, that gets rid of the first change exception error. However it returns 0 rows even though I know there is a row that has the specified date. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `=` instead of `LIKE`

```
 foundRows = dttemp.Select(String.Format("whn = '{0}'", datevalue));
```

Comment: Yeah I did change to = but still returns 0 rows. Not sure why. The "whn" column is formatted as DateTime. Does this affect it?

Comment: if you're searching a datetime column you have to surround the value with # so something like: foundRows = dttemp.Select(String.Format("whn = #{0}#", datevalue));

Comment: No it does not affect it. But if time portion are compared they may not match - the time difference

Comment: This won't work for values in the DataTable that have fractions of a second - the default format ("g") that you're using doesn't include fractions of a second.  See my answer.