# How do I stop a date/time comparison from failing when a user is in a different time zone?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I am getting the "LastWriteTime" of my executable and comparing it to an internal DateTime that I have set.  If the LastWriteTime is less than or equal to the internal DateTime then I will clear two tables from a database.

This code works great for me in the Pacific Time Zone.  But if a user is in another time zone, (example 4 hours ahead of me), then it does not work because the "LastWriteTime" returns the time converted to their time zone.  For example, I am looking for the value of "12/12/2012 8:38:12 AM" and if they are 4 hours ahead of me, this value gets automatically changed to "12/12/2012 12:38:12 PM" on their systems.

Can someone please show me what I should modify in my code to take into account for different time zones so the "LastWriteTime" and my 'build2023_EXE_Date' variable both return the same Date/Time so my comparision of the two date/time values don't fail regardless of what time zone my end user is in?
I am using .NET 3.5, not .Net 4.x

```
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600962/displaying-the-build-date
string w_file = "MyEXE.exe";
string w_directory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) +
                       Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "MyEXE";

DateTime currentExeTime = File.GetLastWriteTime(System.IO.Path.Combine(w_directory, w_file));


DateTime build2023_EXE_Date = new DateTime(2012, 12, 12, 8, 38, 12); //"12/12/2012 8:38:12 AM"

//We need to truncate the millisecond time off of the EXE LastWriteTime
//or else when we compare to our internal DateTime build2323_EXE_Date value,
//it will not match
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004698/how-to-truncate-milliseconds-off-of-a-net-datetime
currentExeTime = new DateTime(
     currentExeTime.Ticks - (currentExeTime.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond),
            currentExeTime.Kind
            );

if (currentExeTime <= build2023_EXE_Date) //If previous build matches or is before the Build 2023 date then clear these two tables.
{
    //This will fail the comparision if the user is in a different time zone than me.
    //Clear tables
}
```

Comment: Isn't `TimeZone` class for that? ;)

Comment: See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DateTime ToUniversalTime()` method

Comment: Would I just make my comparison look like this?  if (c3.ToUniversalTime() <= build2023_EXE_Date.ToUniversalTime())

Comment: In case of build2023_EXE_Date there is no information about timezone, so either set it or just compare build2023_EXE_Date and c3.ToUniversalTime() if you are sure, that build2023_EXE_Date is UTC

Answer (score 4):

Unless you've got a specific need to keep dates in local time or have an associated time zone, I suggest you use universal time instead. This makes working with dates far easier because they all compare sanely, and it can actually be more performant (when you request `DateTime.Now`, .NET calls `DateTime.UtcNow` and then performs a relatively expensive adjustment to local time).

Another option is to use `DateTimeOffset`, which stores a date with an offset (*not a time zone!* -- for instance, DST will give you different offsets) and makes comparisons as easy as a universal `DateTime`. Unfortunately, though, `GetLastWriteTime` doesn't use `DateTimeOffset` so this might not work for you.

Comment: I don't have a specific need to keep the dates in any particular time zone.  I just want to make sure both dates when I compare them are translated to the same time zone when I do the comparison.

Comment: Would using this work for me?  "if (c3.ToUniversalTime() <= build2023_EXE_Date.ToUniversalTime())"    Would that cause the comparison to always pass if the criteria is met regardless of a user's timezone?

Comment: keep the date in the database as a universal time, and have the clients send their time in universal time (only the client knows what time zone they are in, so you can't convert it on the server)