# Strip seconds from datetime

Tags: c#

I want to strip/remove seconds from a DateTime. Starting with a full Datetime like:

```
DateTime datetime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

I want to strip the seconds using any inbuilt function or regular expression.

Input: 08/02/2015 09:22:45

Expected result: 08/02/2015 09:22:00

Comment: i want to expected 08/02/2015 09:22:45 then want to get result only 08/02/2015 09:22:00

Comment: I've inlined some comment you've made into body of the post. Please edit the post yourself to update/clarify if necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to truncate milliseconds off of a .NET DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004698/how-to-truncate-milliseconds-off-of-a-net-datetime)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can do

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
dt = dt.AddSeconds(-dt.Second);
```

to set the seconds to 0.

Comment: Careful: this will NOT strip the milliseconds from the DateTime.

Comment: Careful:Even if you do .AddMilliseconds(-dt.Millisecond) there will still be fractions of a millisecond left over.

Comment: I believe this will remove the milliseconds (and fractions of a millisecond). 

dt= dt.AddTicks(-(dt.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond));

Comment: it's true that the original date will not change, but the return value is tripped

Answer (score 62):

You can create a new instance of date with the seconds set to 0.

```
DateTime a = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime b = new DateTime(a.Year, a.Month, a.Day, a.Hour, a.Minute, 0, a.Kind);

Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Comment: For consistency, I suggest you either use DateTime.Now for creating "a", or add "DateTimeKind.Utc" to the end of the line creating "b".  Creating a UTC time without adding the timezone is likely to cause some strange results.

Comment: to complete Patrick comment, use the ctor with DataTimeKind, so
DateTime b = new DateTime(a.Year, a.Month, a.Day, a.Hour, a.Minute, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
as I just edited

Comment: This does not strip the seconds from the result either. It only sets them to 0.

Comment: This was safe direct and easy readable journey and got me there.

Answer (score 15):

`DateTime` is actually stored separately as a `Date` and a `TimeOfDay`. We can easily re-initialize the date without including the seconds in the `TimeSpan` initialization. This also ensures any leftover milliseconds are removed.

```
date = date.Date + new TimeSpan(date.TimeOfDay.Hours, date.TimeOfDay.Minutes, 0);
```

Answer (score 10):

A simple solution which strips both seconds and milliseconds from a DateTime:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
DateTime secondsStripped = dt.Date.AddHours(dt.Hour).AddMinutes(dt.Minute);
```

Answer (score 6):

How about this rather elegant solution?

```
new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / 600000000 * 600000000)
```

... which will also strip any milli/micro/nanoseconds.

Comment: There's an extra 0 there. You mean / 10_000_000.

Comment: The question was about stripping seconds off a DateTime. But you were right about something being wrong. There are 60 seconds in a minute, not 100 ;) I fixed the answer. By the way: you might wanna update your answer too, since its wrong (not stripping off seconds). Also the syntax error (the underscores) aren't too obvious for junior coders.

Comment: ok. since I didn't see a 6 I thought you were trying to strip the milliseconds.

Answer (score 4):

And as an extension, keeps the kind and also trims milliseconds

```
public static DateTime TrimSeconds(this DateTime a)
{
    return new DateTime(a.Year, a.Month, a.Day, a.Hour, a.Minute, 0, a.Kind);
}
```

Comment: This does not strip the seconds from the result either. It only sets them to 0.

Comment: @wEight And what happens to the zeroes in the original questions sample of the expexted results? I dont think anyone expects them to be "gone" from a DateTime

Answer (score 2):

```
// 2.3 - 0.3 = 2.0
public static DateTime Floor(this DateTime value, TimeSpan interval) {
    var mod = value.Ticks % interval.Ticks;
    return value.AddTicks( -mod );
}

// 2.3 - 0.3 + 1 = 3.0
public static DateTime Ceil(this DateTime value, TimeSpan interval) {
    var mod = value.Ticks % interval.Ticks;
    if (mod != 0) return value.AddTicks( -mod ).Add( interval );
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a local time you can use:

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
dt = dt.AddTicks(-(dt.Ticks % (60 * 10_000_000)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
string timestring = time.ToString("g");
```

`ToString("g")` will convert `DateTime` to string and remove seconds.

Output: `03/29/2018 11:11 PM`

Comment: You'd have to parse it back to a DateTime though to be compliant with OP's request to get a DateTime, not a string.

Comment: Small correction to this -- ("g") outputs as military time, thus you would not see "03/29/2018 11:11 PM" but instead will get "03/29/2018 23:11"

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but I've always used "Ticks" arithmetic to do these kinds of things. A straightforward way to "truncate" seconds (and any milliseconds) is:

```
var d1 = DateTime.Now;
var noSeconds = new DateTime(d1.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute * TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute);
```

Of course I've encapsulated all of it in neat functions:

```
public static long Round(this long dateTicks, TimeSpan span) {
    long ticks = (dateTicks + (span.Ticks / 2)) / span.Ticks;
    return ticks * span.Ticks;
}
public static long Floor(this long dateTicks, TimeSpan span) {
    long ticks = (dateTicks / span.Ticks);
    return ticks * span.Ticks;
}
```

You can see there's a `Round` method which will round upward if the "span" is halfway to the next interval (31 seconds will round up for example, while 30 will round down). To strip a period, just use the `Floor` method. The following console script will show how to use these:

```
using System;

public static long Round(this long dateTicks, TimeSpan span) {
    long ticks = (dateTicks + (span.Ticks / 2)) / span.Ticks;
    return ticks * span.Ticks;
}
public static long Floor(this long dateTicks, TimeSpan span) {
    long ticks = (dateTicks / span.Ticks);
    return ticks * span.Ticks;
}
                
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2022, 03, 31, 08, 30, 31, 235);
DateTime d2 = new DateTime(Floor(d1.Ticks, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)));
DateTime d3 = new DateTime(Round(d1.Ticks, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)));

Console.WriteLine(d1);
Console.WriteLine(d2);
Console.WriteLine(d3);
```

Which will result int:

```
3/31/2022 8:30:31 AM
3/31/2022 8:30:00 AM
3/31/2022 8:31:00 AM
```

You could also have rounded or floored in any time span: 5 seconds, 30 seconds, half an hour, etc.

With these Tick-based methods I've created a bunch of overloaded extension methods for many "data and time" types. Feel free to use however you wish:

```
using System;

public static class DateAndTimeExtensions
{
    public static long Round(this long dateTicks, TimeSpan span) {
        long ticks = (dateTicks + (span.Ticks / 2)) / span.Ticks;
        return ticks * span.Ticks;
    }
    public static long Round(this long dateTicks, TimeSpan span, TimeSpan grace) {
        long ticks = (dateTicks + (span.Ticks - grace.Ticks)) / span.Ticks;
        return ticks * span.Ticks;
    }
    public static long Floor(this long dateTicks, TimeSpan span) {
        long ticks = (dateTicks / span.Ticks);
        return ticks * span.Ticks;
    }
    public static long Ceil(this long dateTicks, TimeSpan span) {
        long ticks = (dateTicks + span.Ticks - 1) / span.Ticks;
        return ticks * span.Ticks;
    }

    public static DateTime Round(this DateTime date, TimeSpan span)
        => new DateTime(date.Ticks.Round(span));
    public static DateTime Round(this DateTime date, TimeSpan span, TimeSpan grace)
        => new DateTime(date.Ticks.Round(span, grace));
    public static DateTime Floor(this DateTime date, TimeSpan span)
        => new DateTime(date.Ticks.Floor(span));
    public static DateTime Ceil(this DateTime date, TimeSpan span)
        => new DateTime(date.Ticks.Ceil(span));
    public static DateTimeOffset Round(this DateTimeOffset date, TimeSpan span)
        => new DateTimeOffset(date.Ticks.Round(span), date.Offset);
    public static DateTimeOffset Round(this DateTimeOffset date, TimeSpan span, TimeSpan grace)
        => new DateTimeOffset(date.Ticks.Round(span, grace), date.Offset);
    public static DateTimeOffset Floor(this DateTimeOffset date, TimeSpan span)
        => new DateTimeOffset(date.Ticks.Floor(span), date.Offset);
    public static DateTimeOffset Ceil(this DateTimeOffset date, TimeSpan span)
        => new DateTimeOffset(date.Ticks.Ceil(span), date.Offset);
    public static TimeSpan Round(this TimeSpan time, TimeSpan span)
        => new TimeSpan(time.Ticks.Round(span));
    public static TimeSpan Round(this TimeSpan time, TimeSpan span, TimeSpan grace)
        => new TimeSpan(time.Ticks.Round(span, grace));
    public static TimeSpan Floor(this TimeSpan time, TimeSpan span)
        => new TimeSpan(time.Ticks.Floor(span));
    public static TimeSpan Ceil(this TimeSpan time, TimeSpan span)
        => new TimeSpan(time.Ticks.Ceil(span));
    public static TimeSpan Abs(this TimeSpan time)
        => new TimeSpan(Math.Abs(time.Ticks));
}
```

Using the above extension methods you can easily truncate or round in any time span you require. Just look at the following examples:

```
var d = new TimeSpan(3, 20, 31); // 3h20min31s
var roundedAt5Seconds = d.Round(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));  // 03:20:30
var roundedAt1Minute = d.Round(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));   // 03:21:00
var flooredAt1Minute = d.Floor(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));   // 03:20:00
var roundedAtHalfHour = d.Round(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)); // 03:30:00
var flooredAtHalfHour = d.Floor(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)); // 03:00:00
```