# subtract datetime.now from a datetime.now and truncat the millisecond

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have the following inside my asp.net mvc web application:-

```
 scan.StartDate = System.DateTime.Now;
//do long job....
 scan.EndDate = System.DateTime.Now;

    var duration = (scan.EndDate - scan.StartDate);
```

now the duration will be something such as `00:00:50.0250000` so my question is how i can truncate the miliseconds and show only hour:minute:seconds ?

Comment: In a string? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes i am converting it to a string later on , to send in an email

Comment: Then the link supplied is what you want. It shows how to format the TimeSpan.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004698/how-to-truncate-milliseconds-off-of-a-net-datetime) shows what your are asking, if you need *just formatting* - answers to this post give you a way.

Comment: I would prefer the Stopwatch class.  Your method may occasionally give an inaccurate result, e.g. if daylight savings time starts/ends or the time is adjusted by the Windows Time Service while your long job is running: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var result = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", duration.Hours, duration.Minutes, duration.Seconds);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code which shall remove the milliseconds.[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
DateTime StartDate = System.DateTime.Now;
//do long job....
DateTime EndDate = System.DateTime.Now;               
var duration = (EndDate - StartDate);     
string st=duration.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
```

Comment: this will not work it mentioned mm does not exsits...