# How do I use LinqToSql to query on specific datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, linq-to-sql

When using Linq2Sql to query the database on a specific datetime, the query always comes back with no results. I suspect the times are off by nanoseconds causing the difference. The times must be equal but not that equal. How do I query the database for a datetime, down to just the second for precision?

The following code works but it excludes the time portion altogether:

```
        var Foos = Bars
                .Where(x =>
                    DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.EndDate) == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(endDate))
                .Select(x => x.Id);
```

Also tried this code (which isn't pretty) but the compiler complained about having Date inside a linq query.

```
        var Foo = Bars
                .Where(x => 
                        x.EndDate.Value.Date == endDate.Value.Date &&
                        x.EndDate.Value.Hour == endDate.Value.Hour &&
                        x.EndDate.Value.Minute == endDate.Value.Minute &&
                        x.EndDate.Value.Second == endDate.Value.Second)
                .Select(x => x.Id);
```

Also tried this, but the query always came back empty. Possibly ToString() not working in the Linq query.

```
var foo = bars.Where(x => x.EndDate.ToString() == endDate.ToString())
```

Comment: I had to do something similar some time back and used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004698/how-to-truncate-milliseconds-off-of-a-net-datetime to work it out. I have not tested this with your example.

Comment: Not sure this will work in a linq query, but I'll give it a shot

Comment: Did you try to use the `DiffSeconds` method?

Comment: I thought about it, but wouldn't I also have to check DiffMinutes, DiffHours, DiffDay, etc...

Comment: No, you don't. calculating the seconds difference alone should be enough.

Comment: Yes you're right. Let me try.

Comment: Are you using entity framework? are you using `EntityFunctions` or `DbFunctions`?

Comment: yes entity framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`DiffSeconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.diffseconds(v=vs.113).aspx) method like this:

```
var Foo = Bars
       .Where(x => DbFunctions.DiffSeconds(x.EndDate, endDate) == 0)
       .Select(x => x.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

**A way around is to compare date part and hour part separately**. Instead of trying to cast , lets divide and conquer

Suppose you have the data stored in DB as below

```
Pickup Time :10/9/2015 12:53:15 AM
```

and if you want to compare it present system time up to hours, the below query works

```
 orddb.order.Where(x.PickupDate.Hour >= DateTime.Today.Hour 
                    && x.PickupDate >= DateTime.Today)
```