# Select only records around a certain time

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, filter

In my database, there's a record every single minute. I want to only select every record that's created around every fifteen minutes.

The following code shows how I currently execute this query, but with the statement: `v.CreateTime > v.CreateTime < endDate)`, I'm only declaring between what dates I would like to get the data.

I want the data with times of `:15, :30, :45, :00`. Also the data in not entered in precisely at those times. For example `12:15:23` is possible, but `12:14.43` is also possible.

```
vafDataList = service.LoadVesselRecord<VafData>(v => 
      v.TypeNo == RecordObjectTypes.VafData && 
      v.Vessel_No == vesselNo && 
      v.CreateTime > startDate && 
      v.CreateTime < endDate)
  .OrderBy(t => t.CreateTime)
  .ToList();
```

How can I select only the records around the quarters of an hour, and not all records?

Comment: You have filter by creation time. What is wrong with it?

Comment: That's _very_ trivial, and the code you have will work, if you know _which_ 15 minutes you want. What have you tried? What is your question? What does _"only load a record every 15 minutes one is in there"_ mean? Are you asking for a timer, or for `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15)`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to [truncate the seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004698/how-to-truncate-milliseconds-off-of-a-net-datetime) from the result?

Comment: @CodeCaster No, I just want 4 records an hour instead of 60.. And the records should be the ones around `.15, .30, .45, .00`

Comment: I don't understand your question... what's the problem? Do you want to round the minutes of your datetimes?

Comment: What is the maximum deviation, one minute? So you'll never have to select records created at minute 13 or 17?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes indeed, shouldn't be more as a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply select the records for those minutes:

```
.Where(t => new int[] { 0, 15, 30, 45 }.Contains(t.CreateTime.Minute))
```

However, assuming your `LoadVesselRecord()` calls a `Where()` that gets executed on a `DbSet`, Entity Framework can't translate that to a query, so you'll have to use the `SqlFunctions` extensions to let Entity Framework translate it to a `DATEPART` SQL statement:

```
.Where(t => new int[] { 0, 15, 30, 45 }
            .Contains(SqlFunctions.DatePart("minute", t.CreateTime)))
```

Comment: Going to try this out right away! Getting a little error on the: `new int[] { 0, 15, 30, 45 }`. Can't be converted to IENumerable. So I guess I just add `.ToList()` after that, right?

Comment: You're showing an incomplete message. I suspect you'll need to cast the DatePart to `(int)`.

Comment: Getting this error now.. `Additional information: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities.` The where I ended up with giving no errors: `.Where(f => new int[] { 0, 15, 30, 45 }.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(SqlFunctions.DatePart("minute", f.CreateTime))))`