# How to remove the portion other than date and time from datetime object?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have to compare two datetime objects.

I have `dt1= 08/02/2017 11:37:06` and `dt2=08/02/2017 11:37:06 224`. 
So for sure they do not work in the condition

```
if(dt1>=dt2) {}
```

and

```
if(DateTime.Equals(dt1, dt2)) { }
```

Both of them return false.
How to make them work ? I mean it should go inside the loop (avoiding the 224 part of datetime). I just have to take into account `dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss` and eleminate other things

Comment: Surely you want `if (dt1.Date >= dt2.Date) {}`? Or do you want time without milliseconds?

Comment: Maybe [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004698/how-to-truncate-milliseconds-off-of-a-net-datetime)

Comment: One option would be to check the magnitude of the difference between the dates and compare it to a minimum allowed epsilon, but really we would need to know more specifics to determine exactly what would make sense for your specific case.

Comment: Using Date() truncates the DataTime to midnight.  You can get the hours/minutes/seconds by subtracting the DateTime object from the midnight time.  A DateTime is a double with the Integer portion of the time being the number of days from 1/1/1900 and the fraction being a part of a day like .25 being 6 hours (6 hours /24 hours).

Comment: @Equalsk Yes it should go in the loop. I mean without millisecond.

Comment: @jdweng You can just use the `TimeOfDay` property of `DateTime` to get the time portion.

Comment: @Equalsk So you just want to truncate the milliseconds or would you want something like "11:37:06.999" to be equivalent to "11:37:07.001"?

Comment: I just have to take into account  dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss and eleminate other things .