# Date comparison with MaxValue not working

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a nullable Date property called `BoughtDate`.
I am trying the following:

```
if( item.BoughtDate.Value.Equals( DateTime.MaxValue) ) item.BoughtDate= null;
```

also tried this:

```
if( item.BoughtDate.Equals( DateTime.MaxValue) ) item.BoughtDate=null;
```

When debugging, my `BoughtDate` and `DateTime.MaxValue` seems exactly the same - yet it says it is not the same(does not set my `item.BoughtDate` to null)

Why does my comparison not work?

Comment: Do you need to cast it to a nullable datetime? `item.BoughtDate=(DateTime?)null;`

Comment: Does the `BoughtDate` come from a database?  Differences in the accuracy used to record dates can cause them to superficially appear the same, but differ by a small number of milliseconds (3, usually).

Comment: `bool result = Nullable.Compare(DateTime.Now, yourDate) > 0;`

Comment: Strange! This works well for me and my console statement gets printed  `DateTime? BoughtDate = DateTime.MaxValue;

            if (BoughtDate.Value.Equals(DateTime.MaxValue)) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("equals comparison succeeded");
            }`

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of your visual studio debugger when you are viewing the value present in `item.BoughtDate` in quick watch window?

Comment: The values are probably not the same. Check the Ticks-property of the DateTimes to verify if this is the case.

Answer (score 9):

The problem,as @PaulSuart points in the comments, is probably the milliseconds precision. `DateTime.MaxValue.TimeOfDay` is `{23:59:59.9999999}`,but your `BoughtDate.TimeOfDay` is probably `{23:59:59.9990000}`,so they are not equal.

What i would do is just comparing the dates, i think that's enough in most cases:

```
if( item.BoughtDate.Value.Date.Equals( DateTime.MaxValue.Date) ) item.BoughtDate= null;
```

Comment: Better do add an extension similar to the one this answer suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1005222/68432 - your code is ugly!

Comment: @PaulSuart What do you find "ugly" in comparing the `Date` property of 2 `DateTime` ?

Comment: sorry, I was rude. I just meant that the intent in your code could be expressed more clearly by using an extension method.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As someone pointed out it doesn't answer the original question, just provides an alternative.

Try using DateTime.Compare

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx

```
public static void Main()
{
  DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
  DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0);
  int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
  string relationship;

  if (result < 0)
     relationship = "is earlier than";
  else if (result == 0)
     relationship = "is the same time as";         
  else
     relationship = "is later than";

  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", date1, relationship, date2);
}
```

in your example maybe like that:

```
if(DateTime.Compare(item.BoughtDate.Value,DateTime.MaxValue) == 0) item.BoughtDate=null;
```

Comment: This is a good alternative way to compare datetime values but OP is asking that why the `equals` API is returning wrong result for `DateTime?` (nullable datetime) type.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test for your case:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime? BoughtDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
    //subtract 100 milliseconds from it
    BoughtDate = BoughtDate.Value.AddMilliseconds(-1);

    Console.WriteLine(BoughtDate.Value.Hour); //23
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.MaxValue.Hour); //23

    Console.WriteLine(BoughtDate.Value.Minute); //59
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.MaxValue.Minute); //59

    Console.WriteLine(BoughtDate.Value.Second); //59
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.MaxValue.Second); //59

    Console.WriteLine(BoughtDate.Value.Year); //9999
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.MaxValue.Year); //9999

    Console.WriteLine(BoughtDate.Value.Month); //12
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.MaxValue.Month); //12

    Console.WriteLine(BoughtDate.Value.Day); //31
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.MaxValue.Day); //31

    Console.WriteLine(BoughtDate.Value.Millisecond); //998
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.MaxValue.Millisecond); //999



    if (BoughtDate.Value.Equals(DateTime.MaxValue)) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("equals comparison succeeded"); //doesn't get printed
    }
}
```

After reducing just one millisecond from original value it doesn't passes the equality check condition in if block but if you see the value of `BoughtDate` in quick watch window *they seem exactly the same* as you said (as it shows only year, month, day, hour, minute and second parts).

[image]

It shows millisecond part only when you expand the `+` sign.

So your date time variables must be differing in millisecond part even if they appear to be the same at one glance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find answer in the below link if the Date you are fetching from SQL-Server.
SQL-Server only supports the time range till 23:59:59.997 and this might cause few ticks less than what C# supports. You can just compare the dates as @Pikoh already mentioned.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql