# How to change DateTime field display precision in asp.net Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm working on my first project in asp.net core razor pages and trying to add a creation date time field to my Article model which is by default filled with current date time. I have defined it liked this:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

when I visit the Article creation page, it is shown like this:

```
2019/02/02 09:25:36.377 PM
```

I don't want the second and millisecond to be shown here, but couldn't find a way to remove them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm}")]_

Comment: please review https://stackoverflow.com/q/1004698/125981

Comment: thanks @MarkSchultheiss, the link you pointed to actually solved the problem for me.

Comment: I strongly suggest you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just (put this in the getter)

```
var newdate = CreationDate.AddTicks(-CreationDate .Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute);
```

Or try this out c# 6+

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.AddTicks(-DateTime.Now.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute);
```

Comment: Just a note  DateTime is a value type and thus immutable

Answer (score 0):

You problably want to either use [DateTime.ToString(string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netcore-2.2#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_) to show the date. For example `CreationDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")` would become `2019/02/02 09:25`

Or you can use the [DisplayFormat Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute?view=netcore-2.2). Example

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm}")]
public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: thanks to you and @Steve for your replies, but unfortunately [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm}")] doesn't solve the problem. also I can't use CreationDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm") because i want the formatted date in the edit (creation) form of my article.

Comment: @stratauren if you need to have the format also in edit mode add ApplyFormatInEditMode = true to the annotation

Comment: @Steve I did what you said, but now it only shows yyyy/MM/dd --:-- in my field not the current date time.