# Storing DateTimeOffset value without milliseconds in SQL Server using EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Say I create a `DateTimeOffset` value like this:

```
var dt = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
```

And I want to store this value in SQL Server using EF Core code-first. How do I remove the milliseconds portion, so that the value stored in SQL Server becomes `2020-09-08 14:51:00 +00:00` instead of `2020-09-08 14:51:00.4890984 +00:00`?

Comment: I don't know about EF core but in SQL Server you can have your column defined as a `DateTimeOffset(0)` which means no fractional seconds.

Comment: as Zohar said, you should configure the property on your model by specifying the DateTimeOffset(0) type, either through attributes, or through the fluent configuration

Comment: Thanks. I configured it through fluent api.

Comment: Feel free to post the solution as a self answer, so that other users might benefit from your experience.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Zohar Peled. Define your data as it is supposed to be.

other than that, In c# you can truncate date in this way:

```
dt.AddTicks( - (dt.Ticks % dt.TicksPerMilliseconds));
```

[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1005222/1118978) has more general approach.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the reference. I ended up using Zohar/ESG's approach to configure it at the database level.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Zohar suggestion using Data Attributes on your Model binded to EF:

```
    [Column(TypeName = "datetimeoffset(0)")]
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to use a [value converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions).

The code could look like this (using the answer from [How to truncate milliseconds off of a .NET DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1005222/2618319) for the actual conversion logic):

```cs
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>()
            .Property(e => e.YourProperty)
            .HasConversion(
                v => v.AddTicks(-(dateTime.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond));,
                v => v);
    }
}
```

Of course you can also explicitly define and then reuse the value converter and you can also apply it to all properties of a certain type like 'DateTimeOffset', by iterating over the entities and their properties via `ModelBuilder`.