# Compare two DateTimes with ignoring seconds and milliseconds

Tags: c#, .net

I take two object from database. One is a filename with date init and second one is a `DateTime` object like 2021-08-08 17:32:07.880.

First, I converted filename to datetime with the code shown here:

```
var fileDate = DateTime.ParseExact(filename, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I have to check that the difference between the first date and the second date is 3 hours 15 min or simply 3 hours.

How do I delete seconds and milliseconds of date 2, and compare them?

Comment: `var isEither3Hours_Or_3hrs15mins= new[]{180d,195d}.Contains((firstDate - secondDate).TotalMinutes)`

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004698/how-to-truncate-milliseconds-off-of-a-net-datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go similar to MatJ's recommendation:

You've got your file time, and your DB time, which might have seconds and milliseconds on it. If you do the later one minus the earlier one you get a timespan representing the length of time between the datetimes

```
dBDate - fileDate
```

Timespans have a TotalMinutes property that is a decimal. A timespan of 5 minutes 45 seconds would have a TotalMinutes of 5.75

So, if we cast that to an int it cuts off the seconds; simples!

```
var t = (int)((dBDate - fileDate).TotalMinutes);
```

Now you can compare your `t` for equality to 180 (3h) or 195 (3h15h

Comment: Sorry for that. I didnt get it clearly :/ i just need to take that “ var t” variable into the if statement?

Comment: Yep, `if(t==180) //do whatever happens at 3h` `else if(t==195) //do whatever happens at 3h15`

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to do !

Try following code :

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = (firstDate - secondDate)
timeSpan.CompareTo(new TimeSpan(3, 15, 0)) // hrs, mins, seconds
```

This `CompareTo` method will return 1 if difference between two times is greater than 3 hrs and 15 mins, otherwise, it will return -1

PS:
firstDate and secondDate are in `DateTime`

Comment: I am going to try this ty!! But um should i use any Math function like abs or smth else?

Comment: @kkami-sama if it works for you, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer

Comment: @kkami-sama Substracting to dates gives you a TimeSpan structure. So you may take the [Duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.duration?view=net-5.0) method which gives you a new TimeSpan whose value is the absolute value of the current TimeSpan. So something like `(date1 - date2).Duration().TotalMinutes` And note the difference between Minutes and TotalMinutes - you will the latter one.