# Linq Distinct() is not working with DateTime values

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I am using the following query which I believe should filter my results to return only unique DateTimes but as you can see it is not working; records 2 and 3 are identical in the following image. Each of those records is a clone of another so the dates should be identical in case milliseconds or something I cannot see is affecting the result. Appreciate any insight.

[image: Distinct query not working]

Comment: Please, check if dates of interest have *fractions of seconds*: `12/1/4:22:32.001 != 12/1/4:22:32.005`

Comment: Are you sure the milliseconds are identical?

Comment: (The debugger doesn't show milliseconds in its tooltips)

Comment: The base value of a `DateTime` is the `Tick` or 1/10,000 of  millisecond.  It is unlikely they are all the same even if the month or even second are the same

Comment: Incidentally, it might not matter if this is being translated to SQL but it might be quicker to do your OrderBy after your Distinct in other contexts.. no point sorting a million items, then throwing 999,998 away; should throw away first then sort the reduced remainder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Distinct` compares against exact duplicates. Your screenshot doesn't show milliseconds. So you're almost guaranteed that the values are *not* the same, even though the minutes may be.

Comment: Thank you!!! I used the solution here to round the milliseconds for comparing and that solved the issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004698/how-to-truncate-milliseconds-off-of-a-net-datetime

Answer (score 1):

It seems that dates have different *fractions of seconds*. That's why you see

```
12/5/2021 8:30:48 PM
12/5/2021 8:30:48 PM
```

when actual dates are something like these

```
12/5/2021 8:30:48.123 PM 
12/5/2021 8:30:48.234 PM
```

Let's either *drop* these milliseconds:

```
 ...
 .Select(x => new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, x.Day, x.Hour, x.Minute, x.Second))
 .Distinct()
 ...
```

Or *round* them to nearest second

```
 ...
 .Select(x => new DateTime(x.Year, x.Month, x.Day, x.Hour, x.Minute, x.Second)
    .AddSeconds(x.Millisecond / 500))
 .Distinct()
 ...
```